# Stirling numbers of the second kind on Multiset

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers, multisets

[Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(n, k)$ count the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into $k$ nonempty subsets. What if there were duplicate elements in the set? That is, the set is a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset)?

Comment: It would be good to add the link to the definition of Stirling numbers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: The answer is likely to be somewhat complicated to express.  For example, if the set consists of a single type of element, you get the partition numbers p_{n,k} : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: I think [math] is a pretty useless tag in this site; I've deleted it and added [counting]

Answer (score 2):

There is no known formulation for a general multiset. However, a [paper](http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL13/Griffiths/griffiths11.pdf) at JIS tackles the case where the element 1 occurs multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

By  way  of  enrichment  here   is  a  solution  using  **Power  Group
Enumeration**  in polynomial  form.  This  is not  the most  efficient
algorithm and if we are just after  the count we can in fact do better
by  enumerating all  such set  partitions recursively,  which is  also
included here.  The **PGE** algorithm has a certain chance of actually
leading to  a closed form  expression rather  than the output  of some
procedure, however.

The algorithm  is the  same as  presented at  the following  [MSE link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/)  and  at this  link
[MSE link  II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150016/) (edge
colorings  of  the  cube).  We   require  the  cycle  indices  of  the
permutation  groups  acting on  the  slots  and  on the  values  being
distributed into them. For a multiset

$$A_1^{q_1} A_2^{q_2} \times \cdots \times A_p^{q_p}$$

with $q_k$  the multiplicities  the slots consist  of $Q=  \sum_r q_r$
distinct  slots,  into which  we  distribute  the identifiers  of  the
multisets where that slot is to  reside. We may imagine $q_r$ slots of
type  $r$  forming  a  block,  with  the  blocks  being  adjacent  and
containing only  slots of the  same type. Now  with a block  forming a
multiset  the group  acting  on  these slots  is  the symmetric  group
$S_{q_r}$ with cycle index $Z(S_{q_r}).$  Therefore the cycle index of
the slot permutation group (all  blocks) is $$\prod_r Z(S_{q_r}).$$ On
the other hand the multiset  identifiers are permuted by the symmetric
group $S_Q$ with  cycle index $Z(S_Q).$ These data suffice  to run the
algorithm.  Observe that when we  cover (consult links for the details
of this procedure) the cycles of  a slot permutation with a cycle from
a multiset identifier permutation we  must record the identifiers used
in the covering in a generating  function.  We then obtain the desired
result by replacing the indeterminates in the terms of this generating
function  (once  computed) with  $v^m$  where  $m$  is the  number  of
indeterminates in the term. This yields the generating function by the
number of multisets for all $k$ at once.

We present some  examples. When all $q_r$ are one  we are working with
$p$  distinct  items and  should  obtain  Stirling numbers.  (Stirling
numbers  exemplify  the complexity  of  this  problem as  the  **PGE**
routine  is faster  here  and  takes less  memory  than the  recursive
enumeration routine.   This is because  the slot permutation  group in
this case contains only one element.  The computation was done at this
[MSE   link  III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584213/).)
Indeed we find

```
> add(v^k*stirling2(3,k), k=1..3);  
                         3      2
                        v  + 3 v  + v

> MSETS([1,1,1]);
                         3      2
                        v  + 3 v  + v
> add(v^k*stirling2(7,k), k=1..7);
       7       6        5        4        3       2
      v  + 21 v  + 140 v  + 350 v  + 301 v  + 63 v  + v

> MSETS([seq(1, w=1..7)]);
       7       6        5        4        3       2
      v  + 21 v  + 140 v  + 350 v  + 301 v  + 63 v  + v

> add(v^k*stirling2(10,k), k=1..10);
 10       9        8         7          6          5
v   + 45 v  + 750 v  + 5880 v  + 22827 v  + 42525 v

              4         3        2
     + 34105 v  + 9330 v  + 511 v  + v

> MSETS([seq(1, w=1..10)]);         
 10       9        8         7          6          5
v   + 45 v  + 750 v  + 5880 v  + 22827 v  + 42525 v

              4         3        2
     + 34105 v  + 9330 v  + 511 v  + v
```

On the other hand  when $p=1$ we have $q_1$ like  items and should get
the values of the partition function $p_k(n).$ Here we find once again

```
> add(v^k*part(3,k), k=1..3);     
                          3    2
                         v  + v  + v

> MSETS([3]);                
                          3    2
                         v  + v  + v

> add(v^k*part(7,k), k=1..7);
            7    6      5      4      3      2
           v  + v  + 2 v  + 3 v  + 4 v  + 3 v  + v

> MSETS([7]);                
            7    6      5      4      3      2
           v  + v  + 2 v  + 3 v  + 4 v  + 3 v  + v

> add(v^k*part(10,k), k=1..10);
 10    9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2
v   + v  + 2 v  + 3 v  + 5 v  + 7 v  + 9 v  + 8 v  + 5 v  + v

> MSETS([10]);                 
 10    9      8      7      6      5      4      3      2
v   + v  + 2 v  + 3 v  + 5 v  + 7 v  + 9 v  + 8 v  + 5 v  + v
```

Now of  course it  gets difficult  and interesting  when we  have less
structure in  the size and number  of the source multiset.  Here are a
few last examples:

```
> ENUM([2,3,4]);               
 9      8       7       6        5        4        3       2
v  + 6 v  + 26 v  + 75 v  + 151 v  + 191 v  + 126 v  + 29 v

     + v

> MSETS([2,3,4]);
 9      8       7       6        5        4        3       2
v  + 6 v  + 26 v  + 75 v  + 151 v  + 191 v  + 126 v  + 29 v

     + v

> ENUM([3,4,5]); 
 12      11       10        9        8        7         6
v   + 6 v   + 30 v   + 111 v  + 328 v  + 757 v  + 1331 v

             5         4        3       2
     + 1652 v  + 1264 v  + 474 v  + 59 v  + v

> MSETS([3,4,5]);
 12      11       10        9        8        7         6
v   + 6 v   + 30 v   + 111 v  + 328 v  + 757 v  + 1331 v

             5         4        3       2
     + 1652 v  + 1264 v  + 474 v  + 59 v  + v

> ENUM([2,2,3,3]);
 10       9       8        7        6         5         4
v   + 10 v  + 63 v  + 257 v  + 704 v  + 1223 v  + 1204 v

            3       2
     + 536 v  + 71 v  + v

> MSETS([2,2,3,3]);
 10       9       8        7        6         5         4
v   + 10 v  + 63 v  + 257 v  + 704 v  + 1223 v  + 1204 v

            3       2
     + 536 v  + 71 v  + v
```

The source code is quite compact, with the answer being about half and
the rest for testing and verification.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

MSETS :=
proc(mset)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_sets, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    idx_slots :=
    expand(mul(pet_cycleind_symm(item), item in mset));

    if not(type(idx_slots, `+`)) then
        idx_slots := [idx_slots];
    fi;

    idx_sets :=
    pet_cycleind_symm(add(item, item in mset));

    if not(type(idx_sets, `+`)) then
        idx_sets := [idx_sets];
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_slots do
        for term_b in idx_sets do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q +
                        len_b*
                        add(mul(B[len_b,
                                  len_b*cyc_num+cyc_pos],
                                cyc_pos=1..len_b),
                            cyc_num=0..inst_b-1);
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    map(term -> lcoeff(term)*v^nops(indets(term)),
        expand(res));
end;

part :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local res;

    if n=0 or k=0 then
        return `if`(n=0 and k=0, 1, 0);
    fi;

    if k=1 then return 1 fi;

    res := 0;
    if n >= 1 then
        res := res + part(n-1, k-1);
    fi;
    if n >= k then
        res := res + part(n-k, k);
    fi;

    res;
end;

ENUM :=
proc(mset)
option remember;
local total, flat, recurse, msets, res;

    total := add(item, item in mset);
    flat :=
    [seq(seq(p, q=1..mset[p]), p=1..nops(mset))];

    msets := table(); res := 0;

    recurse :=
    proc(idx, len, part)
    local pos, cur, sorted;

        if idx > total then
            sorted :=
            sort([seq(part[pos], pos=1..len)]);

            if not(type(msets[sorted], `integer`)) then
                res := res + v^len;
                msets[sorted] := 1;
            fi;

            return;
        fi;

        cur := A[flat[idx]];
        for pos to len do
            part[pos] := part[pos]*cur;
            recurse(idx+1, len, part);
            part[pos] := part[pos]/cur;
        od;

        part[len+1] := part[len+1]*cur;
        recurse(idx+1, len+1, part);
        part[len+1] := part[len+1]/cur;
    end;

    recurse(1, 0, Array([seq(1, q=1..total)]));
    res;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two links to get you started:

1. [Eulerian numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Eulerian_numbers_of_the_second_kind) may be helpful (for counting ascents, descents, etc., though i think)
2. Additionally some more useful information may be found [in Stanley's book](http://books.google.com/books?id=EvJg1VjIGyMC&lpg=PA26&dq=multiset%20eulerian%20numbers&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q=multiset%20eulerian%20numbers&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

You divide the Stirling number by the possible permutations of identical elements as this is just changing order within the stars and bars example.

Answer (score -2):

By definition, a [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) only has distinct elements.  If elements are duplicated, then yes, the set in question would be a [multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset).