# Edge coloring of the cube

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, coloring

We have a cube and we are coloring its edges. There are three colors available. We say that the two colorings are the same if one can obtain a second by turning cube and permuting colors. Find the number of different colorings.

Any ideas?

I've found [Pólya enumeration theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#Colored_cubes),
but it's difficult to understand for me, also this approach does not take into account the permutation of colors...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I started working on this using [Burnside's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), I might as well show what I've got. It is easy to make a mistake here.

> Marko Riedel cast a serious doubt on the result. Lo and behold! It turned out that I had made an error in calculating that fraction. Because the erroneous sum still produced an integer I didn't catch it myself.

As described in loc.cit the 24 rotations of the cube split into 5 conjugacy classes. For each class we need to know what kind of orbits a representative in that class (or rather, the cyclic group generated by the representative) has among the edges. We also need to know
the cardinality of the class.

$A$: The class of the identity mapping. Its action on the edges has 12 singleton orbits, and $|A|=1$.

$B$: The class of 90 degree rotations. Its action partitions the edges into 3 orbits with 4 edges in each orbit. $|B|=6.$

$C$: The class of 180 degree rotations about an axis connecting the midpoints of an opposite pair of faces of the cube (the squares of elements of class $B$). The edges are partitioned into 6 pairs. $|C|=3.$

$D$: The class of 120 degree rotations about an axis connecting two opposite vertices. The edges are partitioned to 4 orbits, each with 3 edges. $|D|=8.$

$E$: The class of 180 degree rotations about an axis connecting the midpoints of two parallel but opposite edges. The edges are partitioned into 7 orbits: 2 singletons (the ones intersecting the axis) and 5 pairs. $|E|=6.$

The group of color permutations is isomorphic to $S_3$ and has three conjugacy classes: $a$= the class of the identity mapping, $b$= the class of three 2-cycles (this time swapping two colors and leaving the third color as it is), $c$= the class of two 3-cycles.

The cartesian product of order $24\cdot6=144$ then acts on the set $X$ of colorings. The following table lists the number of fixed points in $X$ that an element of the listed conjugacy class has.

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|ccc|c|c}
\text{class}&\text{size}&|X^g|&&\text{class}&\text{size}&|X^g|\\
\hline
Aa&1&3^{12}&&Cc&6&0\\
Ab&3&1&&Da&8&3^4\\
Ac&2&0&&Db&24&1\\
Ba&6&3^3&&Dc&16&3^4\\
Bb&18&3^3&&Ea&6&3^7\\
Bc&12&0&&Eb&18&3^5\\
Ca&3&3^6&&Ec&12&0\\
Cb&9&3^6&&&&
\end{array}
$$
Feeding these numbers into the formula of Burnside's lemma tells that the number of orbits (=the number of distinguishable colorings under the prescribed rules) is
$$
|X/G|=\frac{1\cdot3^{12}+3\cdot1+6\cdot3^3+18\cdot3^3+3\cdot3^6+9\cdot3^6+8\cdot3^4+24\cdot1+16\cdot3^4+6\cdot3^7+18\cdot3^5}{144}=3891.
$$

How did I come up with these numbers. The details vary a bit case-by-case. As somewhat typical examples consider:

The class $Ab$: Here the edges stay at the same place, but two of the colors are interchanged. A coloring is a fixed point of this operation only if it is monochromatic (of the non-interchanged color). Thus the elements in this class have exactly one fixed point.

The class $Ba$: Here we want to calculate the number of colorings that remain unchanged, when we rotate the cube by 90 degrees, and don't do any repainting. For this to happen it is necessary and sufficient that any of the three groups of four edges permuted among themselves by the rotation must share the same color. We have the liberty of choosing the colors for all the orbits independently. Therefore there are $3^3$ such colorings.

The class $Bb$: Here the 3 groups of 4 edges undergo some repainting in addition to the 90 degree rotation. If the three colors are R,Y,G, and we are to repaint every yellow edge green, and every green edge yellow, then for each orbit the possible colorings are RRRR, YGYG and GYGY. In the latter two cases repainting cancels the effect of the rotation. So we have 3 choice for the three groups of 4 edges, and a total of $3^3$ colorings
fixed under a group action of this type.

The class $Bc$: Here we can assume a color replacement scheme $Y\mapsto R\mapsto G\mapsto Y$. This permutation of order 3 just doesn't mesh with the rotation of order 4, so no colorings are fixed points for this operation.

The class $Dc$: Let's study the same color replacement scheme as with class $Bc$. The 12 edges are partitioned into 4 groups of 3 edges. The coloring of such a group has to be either $RGY$, $GYR$ or $YRG$ for the repainting to cancel the effect of the rotation. But the choices for the four orbits are independent from each other, so we get a total of $3^4$ colorings that are fixed under an operation of this type.

The class $Eb$: Assume color replacement scheme $R\mapsto R$, $Y\mapsto G\mapsto Y$. For a coloring to be a fixed point, the two edges that are rotated in place, must both be red. But for the 5 pairs of edgese that interchange their locations, the possible colorings are $RR$, $YG$ and $GY$ for the same reasons as with class $Bb$.

If you have trouble filling in the rest of the table, @ping me!

Comment: Your solution looks very good but I get a slightly different value also using Burnside. I have computed these with three different methods (generating functions, two ways, Burnside, one way, see below) so you might want to check your computation.

Comment: Belated thanks @Marko. I'm just covering Burnside's lemma in a course. So I will recheck my numbers. It is easy to make a mistake here. I will get back to this ASAP.

Comment: I have re-visited this problem and was able to reduce the Maple code (at end) to just $56$ lines.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel It turned out that all my data was correct. But there was a numerical error in the calculation of that quotient :-) I'm relieved in a sense, but also embarassed :-)

Comment: No need to be. This happens to everybody.

Comment: A numerical error I can live with. At least the table of fixed points seems to be ok!

Comment: I arrived at the same table of fixed points (before looking at the table or any further), so it seems to be ok indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the independent verification @Servaes.

Answer (score 6):

I  would like  to contribute  some enrichment  material  to facilitate
additional exploration of this problem. The most important observation
is  that  what   we  have  here  is  an   instance  of  **Power  Group
Enumeration**, with the group acting on the slots where the $n$ colors
are placed  being the edge permutation  group $E$ of the  cube and the
group acting on  the colors being the symmetric  group on $n$ elements
$S_n$.

We can compute the number  of configurations by Burnside's lemma which
says to average the number of assignments fixed by the elements of the
power  group, which has  $n!\times |E|!$  elements and  $|E|=24$.  But
this  number  is easy  to  compute.   Suppose  we have  a  permutation
$\alpha$ from  $E$ and a permutation  $\beta$ from $S_n.$  If we place
the appropriate number of complete, directed and consecutive copies of
a cycle from $\beta$ on a  cycle from $\alpha$ then this assignment is
fixed  under the  power group  action, and  this is  possible  iff the
length of $\beta$ divides the length of $\alpha$ and there are as many
assignments as the length of $\beta.$

To do this we first need the cycle index of $E$, which we now compute.
There is the identity, which contributes $$a_1^{12}.$$ Rotations about
an  axis  passing through  a  pairs  of  opposite vertices  contribute
$$4\times 2 a_3 ^4.$$ Rotations about an axis passing through opposite
faces  contribute $$3 \times  (2 a_4^3  + a_2^6).$$  Finally rotations
about an  axis passing through midpoints of  opposite edges contribute
$$6\times a_1^2 a_2^5.$$

This gives the cycle index
$$Z(E) = \frac{1}{24}
\left(a_1^{12} + 8 a_3^4 + 6 a_4^3 + 3 a_2^6 + 6 a_1^2 a_2^5\right).$$

Let's verify  this cycle index  before we proceed. For  edge colorings
with $n$ colors where the colors  are not being permuted we obtain the
formula
$$\frac{1}{24}
\left(n^{12} + 8 n^4 + 6 n^3 + 3 n^6 + 6 n^7\right).$$
This gives the sequence
$$1, 218, 22815, 703760, 10194250, 90775566, 576941778, 
2863870080,\ldots$$
which points us  to [OEIS A060530](https://oeis.org/A060530), where we
find that indeed we have the right cycle index.

Now the  Burnside computation  is best  done with a  CAS, here  is the
Maple code.

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

cube_edge_cind :=
1/24*(a[1]^12 + 8*a[3]^4 + 6*a[4]^3 + 3*a[2]^6 + 6*a[1]^2*a[2]^5);

cube_edge_colorings :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx_cols, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n = 1 then return 1 fi;
    idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(n);

    res := 0;

    for term_a in cube_edge_cind do
        for term_b in idx_cols do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

This will produce the following  sequence of values for colorings with
$n$ colors with the symmetric group acting on the colors:
$$1, 114, 3891, 29854, 87981, 143797, 170335, 177160,\ldots$$

**Addendum Jan 29  2019.** The above computation is  easily adapted to
produce a  generating function, making  it possible not only  to count
these  colorings  but  also  to   classify  them  by  the  numbers  of
interchangeable colors  used.  The  technique is  the same  (cover the
cycles of  a term from  $Z(E)$ by  cycles obtained from  a permutation
belonging to $S_n$),  only this time we record the  colors being used.
With  the colors  being interchangeable  we collect  the contributions
corresponding to the  same partition of the twelve  edges according to
the colors into one term. This is the result for three colors:

$${P_{{1}}}^{12}+29\,{P_{{1}}}^{6}{P_{{2}}}^{6}
+38\,{P_{{1}}}^{5}{P_{{2}}}^{7}+27\,{P_{{1}}}^{4}{P_{{2}}}^{8}
+282\,{P_{{1}}}^{4}{P_{{2}}}^{4}{P_{{3}}}^{4}
+13\,{P_{{1}}}^{3}{P_{{2}}}^{9}
\\+1170\,{P_{{1}}}^{3}{P_{{2}}}^{4}{P_{{3}}}^{5}
+412\,{P_{{1}}}^{3}{P_{{2}}}^{3}{P_{{3}}}^{6}
+5\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}}^{10}
+370\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}}^{5}{P_{{3}}}^{5}
\\+600\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}}^{4}{P_{{3}}}^{6}
+340\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}}^{3}{P_{{3}}}^{7}
+77\,{P_{{1}}}^{2}{P_{{2}}}^{2}{P_{{3}}}^{8}
+P_{{1}}{P_{{2}}}^{11}
+236\,P_{{1}}{P_{{2}}}^{5}{P_{{3}}}^{6}
\\+170\,P_{{1}}{P_{{2}}}^{4}{P_{{3}}}^{7}
+85\,P_{{1}}{P_{{2}}}^{3}{P_{{3}}}^{8}
+30\,P_{{1}}{P_{{2}}}^{2}{P_{{3}}}^{9}
+5\,P_{{1}}P_{{2}}{P_{{3}}}^{10}.$$

The Maple code goes as follows.

```
with(combinat);

cube_edge_cind :=
1/24*(a[1]^12 + 8*a[3]^4 + 6*a[4]^3 + 3*a[2]^6 + 6*a[1]^2*a[2]^5);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


pet_indets2rep :=
proc(ip)
local rep, var, deg, pos;

    rep := []; pos := 1;

    for var in indets(ip) do
        for deg to degree(ip, var) do
            rep :=
            [op(rep), [seq(s, s=pos..pos+op(1, var)-1)]];
            pos := pos + op(1, var);
        od;
    od;

    rep;
end;

cube_edge_colorings_gf :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local idx_cols, rep, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, len_a, len_b, p, q,
    parts, alldeg, cols;

    if n = 1 then return P[1]^12 fi;
    idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(n);

    res := 0;

    for term_a in cube_edge_cind do
        for term_b in idx_cols do
            rep := pet_indets2rep(term_b);

            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in rep do
                    len_b := nops(v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*
                        mul(P[col], col in v_b)
                        ^(len_a/len_b);
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;

    parts := 0;

    for cols in expand(res) do
        alldeg :=
        sort(map(v -> degree(cols, v),
                 [op(indets(cols))]));

        parts := parts +
        lcoeff(cols)*
        mul(P[v]^alldeg[v], v=1..nops(alldeg));
    od;

    parts;
end;

cube_edge_colorings :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local gf, sl;

    gf := cube_edge_colorings_gf(n);
    sl := [seq(v = 1, v in indets(gf))];

    subs(sl, gf);
end;
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote  up a how-to with several detailed examples, including counting the number of ways of coloring the *faces* of the cube, on [my blog](http://blog.plover.com/math/polya-burnside.html). That should get you started. I may be able to come back to this answer later to discuss edge colorings, but it's not very different.

*Addendum*: Jyrki has done a very thorough discussion of the fixed points of edge colorings under various actions, and I have nothing much to add to his excellent explanantion except that it is often only little more work to do the analysis in general for $N$ colors, and to get a polynomial in $N$, than it is to do it for some particular $N$, as Jyrki did.

Comment: I don't see, why we would get a polynomial in $N$ as a solution to the $N$-colored version of this problem? Are you saying that it is not just a coincidence, that we got a power of 3 e.g. in the case Bb? May be it isn't? I'll give you a bounty, if you can derive a general formula here (that is, without consuming a full paper's worth of space)!! I would have guessed that the number of conjugacy classess of $S_N$ blowing on your face alone would make it mighty hard. +1 for the link to your blog was already there :-)

Comment: @Jyrki: The solution isn't a polynomial in $N$ because it's constant for $N\ge12$ but not constant for $N\le12$. (By the way, that also means it's easy to derive a general formula, since one would merely have to write a program that counts the patterns up to $N=12$. :-)

Comment: @joriki: By <insert the name of a deity>! You're right! Neat :-)