# How many arrays with crossed cells, order of rows/columns irrelevant

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, matrices, algebraic-graph-theory

I've been struggling with this simple problem for months though as I am a newbie to… well, maths, there's high chance someone more educated than myself may get it right!

Let's consider an array or a table or a Ferrers diagram or whatever it's called,

- $r$ rows by $c$ columns,
- in which each cell can either be blank or have a cross in it
- but each column must contain exactly $a$ crosses.

For instance, $\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline ×&×&×&×& &  \\
\hline ×&×& & &×&× \\
\hline  & &×& &×&  \\
\hline  & & &×& &× \\
\hline
\end{array}$ is such an array with $c=6,\ r=4,\ a=2$.

Now two arrays are said to be identical ('isomporphic' is probably the right word?) if we can obtain the second one from the first one by changing the order of columns and/or rows of the first one. So, the following array is identical to the one above:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline  & & &×& &× \\
\hline ×&×& & &×&× \\
\hline  &×&×& & &  \\
\hline ×& &×&×&×&  \\
\hline
\end{array}$

but the order of columns is changed to $164325$ and the order of rows to $3241$.

**Now the question is:** how many unidentical (non-isomorphic) arrays are there, such that all the above conditions are satisfied and $c,r,a$ are given?

I know the answer for $c=6,r=4,a=2$ is $32$ because I have painstakingly went through every combination but how to do this more effectively?? :) I've been trying to learn enough group theory but it's all about rotating cubes or necklaces and I can't figure out how to translate this simple problem so that its tools can be deployed. Also, I tried to find a recurrence (by slicing away the last row and column) but it seems to be dependent on the actual placement of the crosses so…

I'd be glad for any help…

Comment: I just came across your question and even though I know nothing about group theory it reminds me of a similar problem. For a matrix r by c, consider expanding it to a square matrix of size max(r, c), by concatenating empty rows or columns to fill it. Now it looks like a problem of finding whether 2 directed graphs are isomorphic.

Comment: With $a = 2$, a matrix such as this can be interpreted as an incidence matrix for an undirected graph.  The columns correspond to edges, the rows correspond to vertices, and you have stipulated that each edge is incident with exactly two vertices.

The permutation groups acting on the set of edges and vertices, respectively, are essentially relabeling them.  So, considering matrices up to permutation actions is equivalent to considering the graphs up to relabeling (i.e. isomorphism).

Comment: The generalization to arbitrary $a$ gives matrices in bijection with $a$-uniform hypergraphs.  (These are like graphs, but $a$ vertices at a time are considered as an "edge").  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph

Comment: Or it is the description of a bipartite graph, rows and columns corresponding to the two classes of vertices and crosses where edges are.

Answer (score 2):

**Preliminary  remark.** None  of the  sequences that  appear  in this
problem have  OEIS entries  with one exception.   Therefore I  was not
able to verify  the following results except in a  few cases for small
values.    The  reader  is   invited  to   contribute  this   type  of
verification. An  algorithm to independently verify  the results below
for cases where $k\ge 5$ say would be most welcome.

**Main text.** What I am about to contribute is enrichment material to
facilitate additional  exploration of this problem. We  will treat the
case of a  square grid containing $n$ rows and  columns with $k$ marks
being placed in  each column.  The most important  observation is that
what we have here is  an instance of **Power Group Enumeration**, with
the group  acting on the slots  where a selection  from the ${n\choose
k}$  possible column  configurations  are placed  being the  symmetric
group  $S_n$ on $n$  elements and  the group  $Q_{n,k}$ acting  on the
column vectors being  the  action  induced  on  the set of  columns by
permuting rows.

We can compute the number  of configurations by Burnside's lemma which
says to average the number of assignments fixed by the elements of the
power group,  which has  $n!\times n!$ elements.   But this  number is
easy to  compute.  Suppose we  have a permutation $\alpha$  from $S_n$
(column permutations)  and a  permutation $\beta$ from  $S_n$ (induced
action  on  the  columns  by  row  permutations).   If  we  place  the
appropriate number  of complete, directed and consecutive  copies of a
cycle from  $\beta$ on a cycle  from $\alpha$ then  this assignment is
fixed  under the  power group  action, and  this is  possible  iff the
length of $\beta$ divides the length of $\alpha$ and there are as many
assignments  as the  length of  $\beta.$ We  can work  with  the cycle
indices of  $S_n$ and $Q_{n,k}$  and do not  need to iterate  over all
$n!^2$ permutations.

To do this we need the cycle index $Z(Q_{n,k})$ of $Q_{n,k}$, which we
compute.  as  follows: for each  permutation shape that occurs  in the
cycle   index  $Z(S_n)$   of  the   symmetric  group   we   compute  a
representative  permutation  and  apply   it  to  the  set  of  column
configurations. The result is  factored into disjoint cycles and added
to $Z(Q_{n,k})$ with the coefficient it had in $Z(S_n).$ Very simple.

As an example, here is the cycle index for $Q_{6, 2}:$
$${\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{15}}{720}}+1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{7}{a_{{2}}}^{4}+1
/18\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{3}}}^{4}+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{6}
+1/4\,a_{{1}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}a_{{2}}\\+1/6\,a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{2}a_{{1
}}a_{{6}}+1/5\,{a_{{5}}}^{3}+1/18\,{a_{{3}}}^{5}+1/6\,{a_{{6}}}^
{2}a_{{3}}$$
and this is $Z(Q_{7, 4})$
$$1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{6}}}^{3}{a_{{3}}}^{4}a_{{2}}+1/6\,{a_{{4
}}}^{7}{a_{{2}}}^{3}a_{{1}}+1/7\,{a_{{7}}}^{5}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}
^{35}}{5040}}+1/6\,{a_{{6}}}^{5}a_{{2}}a_{{3}}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}
^{15}{a_{{2}}}^{10}}{240}}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{5}{a_{{3}}}^{10}}{
72}}+1/48\,{a_{{2}}}^{14}{a_{{1}}}^{7}+1/10\,{a_{{5}}}^{7}\\+1/48
\,{a_{{2}}}^{16}{a_{{1}}}^{3}+1/18\,{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{3}}}^{11}+
1/24\,a_{{1}}{a_{{6}}}^{4}{a_{{3}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}\\+1/10\,{a_{{
5}}}^{3}{a_{{10}}}^{2}+1/12\,a_{{4}}{a_{{12}}}^{2}a_{{6}}a_{{1}}$$
and finally this is $Z(Q_{7,5})$
$$1/12\,{a_{{3}}}^{3}a_{{6}}{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{{2}}}^{2}+1/8\,{a_{{4
}}}^{4}{a_{{2}}}^{2}a_{{1}}+1/7\,{a_{{7}}}^{3}+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}
^{21}}{5040}}+1/6\,{a_{{6}}}^{3}a_{{3}}\\+{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{11}{a
_{{2}}}^{5}}{240}}+{\frac {{a_{{3}}}^{5}{a_{{1}}}^{6}}{72}}+1/48
\,{a_{{1}}}^{5}{a_{{2}}}^{8}+1/24\,{a_{{4}}}^{4}a_{{2}}{a_{{1}}}
^{3}+1/10\,{a_{{5}}}^{4}a_{{1}}\\+1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{9}
+1/18\,{a_{{3}}}^{7}+1/24\,a_{{3}}{a_{{6}}}^{2}{a_{{1}}}^{2}{a_{
{2}}}^{2}\\+1/10\,{a_{{5}}}^{2}a_{{10}}a_{{1}}+1/12\,a_{{4}}a_{{2}
}a_{{12}}a_{{3}}.$$

The similarity in the coefficients is because these are inherited from
the symmetric group.

Now the  Burnside computation  is best  done with a  CAS, here  is the
Maple code.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
        option remember;

        if n=0 then return 1; fi;

        expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
        local terml, d, cf, v;

        terml := [];

        cf := varp;
        for v in indets(varp) do
            d := degree(varp, v);
            terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
            cf := cf/v^d;
        od;

        [cf, terml];
end;


pet_autom2cycles :=
proc(src, aut)
        local numa, numsubs;
        local marks, pos, cycs, cpos, clen;

        numsubs := [seq(src[k]=k, k=1..nops(src))];
        numa := subs(numsubs, aut);

        marks := Array([seq(true, pos=1..nops(aut))]);

        cycs := []; pos := 1;

        while pos <= nops(aut) do
              if marks[pos] then
                 clen := 0; cpos := pos;

                 while marks[cpos] do
                       marks[cpos] := false;
                       cpos := numa[cpos];
                       clen := clen+1;
                 od;

                 cycs := [op(cycs), clen];
              fi;

              pos := pos+1;
        od;

        return mul(a[cycs[k]], k=1..nops(cycs));
end;


pet_flat2rep :=
proc(f)
    local p, q, res, cyc, t, len;

    q := 1; res := [];

    for t in f do
        len := op(1, t);
        cyc := [seq(p, p=q+1..q+len-1), q];
        res := [op(res), seq(cyc[p], p=1..nops(cyc))];
        q := q+len;
    od;

    res;
end;

pet_nchoosek_cind :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local idx_slots, cind, src, aut, q, rep, flat, term;

    cind := 0;

    src := choose(n, k);

    if n=1 then
       idx_slots := [a[1]]
    else
       idx_slots := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    for term in idx_slots do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(term);
        rep := pet_flat2rep(flat[2]);

        aut :=
        map(sel -> sort([seq(rep[sel[q]], q=1..k)]), src);

        cind := cind + flat[1]*pet_autom2cycles(src, aut);
    od;

    cind;
end;


matrix_marks :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local idx_cols, idx_marks, res, a, b,
    flat_a, flat_b, cyc_a, cyc_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n=1 then
       idx_cols := [a[1]]
    else
       idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    idx_marks := pet_nchoosek_cind(n, k);
    if not type(idx_marks, `+`) then
        idx_marks := [idx_marks];
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for a in idx_cols do
        flat_a := pet_flatten_term(a);

        for b in idx_marks do
            flat_b := pet_flatten_term(b);

            p := 1;
            for cyc_a in flat_a[2] do
                len_a := op(1, cyc_a);
                q := 0;

                for cyc_b in flat_b[2] do
                    len_b := op(1, cyc_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q;
            od;

            res := res + p*flat_a[1]*flat_b[1];
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

This will produce the following sequence of values for matrices with a
single   mark per column:
$$1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 15, 22, 30, 42, 56, 77, 101, 135, \ldots$$
which is [OEIS A000041](https://oeis.org/A000041).

For two marks per column we get starting at $n=2$
$$1, 3, 11, 35, 132, 471, 1806, 7042, 28494, 118662, 510517, 2262738, 
\\ 10337474, 48625631,\ldots$$

For three marks per column we get starting at $n=3$
$$1, 5, 35, 410, 6178, 122038, 2921607, 81609320, 2588949454, 
\\91699869557, 3582942335285, 153048366545566, 
\\7096576775166579, 355120233277118103,\ldots$$

Finally for four marks per column we get starting at $n=4,$
$$1, 7, 132, 6178, 594203, 85820809, 16341829155, 3875736708590,
\\ 1112175913348040, 378860991866916370, 151006214911844288232,
\\ 69600017255860985666964, 36729204987785981237238642,\ldots$$
The shared values in these three lists represent the fact that
$${n\choose k} = {n\choose n-k}.$$

There is another example of **Power Group Enumeration** at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150016/).

**Addendum 2014-09-23.** By way of an incentive to investigate and develop algorithms to verify the above results for non-trivial values of $n$ and $k$ I present a Perl script (admittedly very simple: warning, exponential algorithm) that can be used to verify small values. It gave the following results.

```
$ time ./mmpg.pl 5 3
cases: 100000
35

real    0m5.377s
user    0m5.179s
sys     0m0.030s

$ time ./mmpg.pl 6 2
cases: 11390625
132

real    12m24.638s
user    11m35.514s
sys     0m0.390s

$ time ./mmpg.pl 6 3
cases: 64000000
410

real    76m39.028s
user    71m55.408s
sys     0m2.261s

$ time ./mmpg.pl 6 4
cases: 11390625
132

real    16m23.239s
user    15m31.747s
sys     0m0.389s

$ time ./mmpg.pl 7 1
cases: 823543
15

real    2m19.743s
user    2m16.937s
sys     0m0.077s

$ time ./mmpg.pl 8 1
cases: 16777216
22

real    99m47.460s
user    93m49.700s
sys     0m2.667s
```

This is the Perl script.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
#

sub permute {
    my ($n) = @_;

    return [[1]] if $n == 1;

    my ($res, $perm) = ([]);

    foreach my $perm (@{ permute($n-1) }){
        my $nxt;

        for(my $pos = 0; $pos < $n; $pos++){
            $nxt = 
                [@$perm[0..($pos-1)], $n, 
                 @$perm[$pos..($n-2)]];
            push @$res, $nxt;
        }
    }

    return $res;
}

sub choose {
    my ($data, $pos, $n) = @_;

    my $size = scalar(@$data);

    return [] if $pos == $size;

    if($n == 1){
        my @res = map { [$_] } @$data[$pos..$size-1];

        return \@res;
    }

    my $rec = choose($data, $pos+1, $n);
    foreach my $sel (@{ choose($data, $pos+1, $n-1) }){
        my $nxt = [@$sel];
        unshift @$nxt, $data->[$pos];

        push @$rec, $nxt;
    }

    return $rec;
}


MAIN: {
    my $n = shift || 4;
    my $k = shift || 3;

    my $range = [0..($n-1)];
    my $cols = choose($range, 0, $k);

    my $opts = scalar(@$cols); my $cases = $opts ** $n;
    print STDERR "cases: $cases\n";

    my $col2ind = {};
    for(my $colind = 0; $colind < $opts; $colind++){
        $col2ind->{join('-', @{ $cols->[$colind] })} 
        = $colind;
    }

    my $seen = {}; my $nperms = permute($n);

    for(my $matind = 0; $matind < $cases; $matind++){
        my $matvec = []; my ($pos, $ind);

        for(($pos, $ind)= (0, $matind); 
            $pos < $n; $pos++){
            my $d = $ind % $opts;

            push @$matvec, $d;
            $ind = ($ind-$d)/$opts;
        }

        for($pos = 0; $pos < $n-1; $pos++){
            last if $matvec->[$pos] > $matvec->[$pos+1];
        }
        next if $pos < $n-1;

        my $admit = 1; my $pid;
        foreach my $perm (@{ $nperms }){
            my @permcols = ();

            foreach(my $colind = 0; $colind < $n; 
                    $colind++){
                my @permcol = 
                    map {
                        $perm->[$_] - 1
                } @{$cols->[$matvec->[$colind]]};


                @permcol = sort { $a <=> $b } @permcol;

                my $pcolind = $col2ind->{join('-', @permcol)};
                push @permcols, $pcolind;
            }

            @permcols = sort { $a <=> $b } @permcols;
            $pid = join('-', @permcols);

            if(exists($seen->{$pid})){
                $admit = undef;
                last;
            }
        }

        $seen->{$pid} = 1 if defined($admit);
    }

    print scalar(keys(%$seen)) . "\n";

    1;
}
```

The above sequences now have OEIS entries as of today:
[OEIS A247417](https://oeis.org/A247417),
[OEIS A247596](https://oeis.org/A247596),
[OEIS A247597](https://oeis.org/A247597),
[OEIS A247598](https://oeis.org/A247598).

**Addendum 2019-05-01.** Consulting the OEIS links from above five
years  after I  first solved  this problem  by **PGE**  we see  that a
better, more efficient and  more sophisticated algorithm has appeared,
placing  the above  in the  category  of a  historical artefact.  Note
however that the  Maple code admits some improvements  which are shown
below (duplicate routines have been omitted).

```
pet_prod2rep :=
proc(varp)
    local v, d, q, res, len, cyc;

    q := 1; res := [];

    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        len := op(1, v);

        for cyc to d do
            res :=
            [op(res),
             seq(p, p=q+1..q+len-1), q];
            q := q+len;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;


pet_nchoosek_cind :=
proc(n, k)
    option remember;
    local idx_slots, cind, src, aut, q, rep, term;

    cind := 0;

    src := choose(n, k);

    if n=1 then
       idx_slots := [a[1]]
    else
       idx_slots := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    for term in idx_slots do
        rep := pet_prod2rep(term);

        aut :=
        map(sel -> sort([seq(rep[sel[q]], q=1..k)]), src);

        cind := cind + lcoeff(term)*pet_autom2cycles(src, aut);
    od;

    cind;
end;


matrix_marks :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local idx_cols, idx_marks, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n=1 then
        idx_cols := [a[1]]
    else
        idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    fi;

    idx_marks := pet_nchoosek_cind(n, k);
    if not type(idx_marks, `+`) then
        idx_marks := [idx_marks];
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_cols do
        for term_b in idx_marks do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

Comment: Having come back to this problem after some time, let me ask: this solution, as well as the Perl script presented, pertains to the special case of a square matrix, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but it is not difficult to adapt it to generic rectangular matrices. You should probably read my remark from today, however (at end).