# Cube edges coloring with 3 colours

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

What is the number of colourings for cube edges in 5 Blue, 3 Green, 4 Red?

Using [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma), I've calculated the group cycle index, which is:

$$ P(G) = \frac{1}{24}(a^{12}+8a^{4}+6a^{3}+3a^{6}+6a^{7})$$

But what's the next step? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this computation we need the cycle index $Z(E)$ of $E$, the action
of the rotations of the cube on the edges which we now compute.  There
is the  identity, which  contributes $$a_1^{12}.$$ Rotations  about an
axis passing through a pairs of opposite vertices contribute $$4\times
2 a_3  ^4.$$ Rotations  about an axis  passing through  opposite faces
contribute $$3 \times (2 a_4^3  + a_2^6).$$ Finally rotations about an
axis passing through midpoints  of opposite edges contribute $$6\times
a_1^2 a_2^5.$$

This gives the cycle index
$$Z(E) = \frac{1}{24}
\left(a_1^{12} + 8 a_3^4 + 6 a_4^3 + 3 a_2^6 + 6 a_1^2 a_2^5\right).$$

Let's verify  this cycle index  before we proceed. For  edge colorings
with $n$ colors where the colors  are not being permuted we obtain the
formula
$$\frac{1}{24}
\left(n^{12} + 8 n^4 + 6 n^3 + 3 n^6 + 6 n^7\right).$$
This gives the sequence
$$1, 218, 22815, 703760, 10194250, 90775566, 576941778,
2863870080,\ldots$$

which points us to  [OEIS A060530](https://OEis.org/A060530), where we
find that indeed we have the right cycle index.

The desired quantity is by the Polya Enumeration Theorem,

$$[R^4 G^3 B^5] Z(E; R+G+B) \\ =
[R^4 G^3 B^5] \frac{1}{24}
\left((R+G+B)^{12}
+ 8 (R^3 + G^3 + B^3)^4
+ 6 (R^4 + G^4 + B^4)^3 \\
+ 3 (R^2 + G^2 + B^2)^6
+ 6 (R + G + B)^2 (R^2 + G^2 + B^2)^5\right)
\\ = [R^4 G^3 B^5] \frac{1}{24} (R+G+B)^{12}
+ [R^4 G^3 B^5] \frac{1}{4}
(R + G + B)^2 (R^2 + G^2 + B^2)^5
\\ = \frac{1}{24} {12\choose 4, 3, 5}
+ \frac{1}{2} [R^4 G^2 B^4] (R^2 + G^2 + B^2)^5
\\ = \frac{1}{24} {12\choose 4, 3, 5}
+ \frac{1}{2} [R^2 G^1 B^2] (R + G + B)^5
\\ = \frac{1}{24} {12\choose 4, 3, 5}
+ \frac{1}{2} {5\choose 2, 1, 2} = 1170.$$

Some   of    this   material   appeared   at    the   following   [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150016/).

Comment: thank you so much! One more question, how exactly you did the transition from the 3rd line to the 4th in the last computation? I mean there're 6 brackets and on the next step, there're only 3.

Comment: In the second term we get the powers being all multiples of three, in  the third of four, and in the fourth of two -- none of these can possibly contribute to the coefficient on $[R^4 G^3 B^5].$