# Way to compute Stirling numbers of the second kind from a multiset

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering what algorithm would compute

```
S(n, k {occurences of each element})
```

Where

```
S(6, 3, {1, 2, 3} )
```

would give the total number of ways a set with 6 elements in which 3 are the same element and a different 2 are another element (and 1 is its unique element) could be split into 3 non-empty sets, ignoring permutations.

This is basically the extension of Stirling numbers of the second kind to deal with multisets.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: How to compute number of unique ways to split a multiset into a given number of non-empty subsets.  
Ignore permutations, and treat all repeated elements as identical.

Comment: No, that's not my question. What is the actual problem that gave rise to this question? Why is this particular combinatorics question of interest?

Comment: I was simply learning about stirling numbers and was thinking about how to expand it to deal with repeated elements. There's no general formula for it, so I was looking for an algorithm to do so

Comment: Interesting question, but probably better suited for the math stackexchange.

Comment: Yes, this is a combinatorics question, not a computational one.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combinatorics.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/q/16890/23353 (I didn't spend enough time to compare.)