# Number of ways colour $n$ distinct objects with at most $n$ different colours without permutations of colours

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that I have $n$ distinct objects. In how many ways can I colour the $n$ objects with at most $n$ distinct colours up to permutations of colours. For e.g

$1,1,1,1$ is the same thing as $2,2,2,2$

$1,1,2,3$ is the same thing as $4,4,1,2$
but $1,1,2,3$ is different from $2,3,1,1$

My approach is count the number of ways to use exactly $i \leq n$ colours to colour the $n$ objects using the inclusion-exclusion principle then divide by $ \binom{n}{i}$. Then I add everything up. However I'm not sure if the method is correct and I'm also looking for a general solution in terms on $n$.

Comment: [Burnside's lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) is the way to go, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to count is the number of different partitions of an $n$ element *set* into $\leq n$ nonempty subsets. The number of these partitions is the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_n$. There is a recursive formula for these and an asymptotic formula involving the Lambert $W$-function.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't see the problem was simply a partition of a set.

Answer (score 0):

By way of enrichment  I would like to point out that  this can also be
done  by  **Power  Group  Enumeration**   as  defined  by  Harary  and
Palmer. Here we  have that the slot permutation group  is the identity
$E_n$ with  cycle index  $Z(E_n) = a_1^n$  and the  object permutation
group  is the  symmetric group  $S_n$ with  cycle index  given by  the
exponential formula

$$Z(S_n) = [z^n] \exp\left(\sum_{l\ge 1} a_l \frac{z^l}{l}\right).$$

Now to apply **PGE** we must cover the single permutation $a_1^n$ with
cycles from  the permutations in  $Z(S_n).$ Clearly if the  latter has
$k$ fixed  points this can be  done in $k^n$ ways.  Hence we introduce
the mixed generating function with fixed points marked

$$G(z, u) = \exp\left(uz-z+\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right).$$

The answer is thus given by (we turn $u^k z^n$ into $k^n z^n$)

$$ [z^n] \left. \left(u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)^n G(z, u)
\right|_{u=1}
\\ =  [z^n] \left. \left(u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)^n
\frac{1}{1-z} \exp(z(u-1))
\right|_{u=1}
\\ =   \left. \left(u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)^n
\sum_{q=0}^n \frac{(u-1)^q}{q!}
\right|_{u=1}
\\ =   \left. \left(u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\right)^n
\sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} u^p
\right|_{u=1}
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} p^n.$$

We recognize Stirling  numbers at this point but we  may also continue
with the EGF

$$F(w) = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^n}{n!}
\sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} p^n
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{w^n}{n!}
\sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} n! [v^n] \exp(pv)
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n [v^n]
\sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!}
\sum_{p=0}^q {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p} \exp(pv)
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n [v^n]
\sum_{q=0}^n \frac{1}{q!}
(\exp(v)-1)^q.$$

Now since $\exp(v)-1=v+\cdots$  we may extend $q$ beyond  $n$ as there
is no contribution to the  coefficient extractor $[v^n]$ in that case,
getting

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} w^n [v^n]
\sum_{q\ge 0} \frac{1}{q!}
(\exp(v)-1)^q
\\ = \sum_{n\ge 0} w^n [v^n] \exp(\exp(v)-1)
= \exp(\exp(w)-1)$$

and we see  that we indeed have  Bell numbers here as  observed in the
reply that  was first to appear.  Note also that **PGE**  rests on the
Burnside lemma which was suggested in the comments.