# A 4 × 4 grid of squares is filled in, with each of the 16 squares colored either black or white...

Tags: combinatorics

A 4 × 4 grid is filled in, with each of the 16 squares colored either black or white. Two colorings are regarded as identical if one can be converted to each other by performing any combination of flipping, rotating, or swapping the two colors (flipping all the black squares to white and vice versa). How many non-identical colorings are there?

I've figured out the number of invariances for each individual transformation but the combinations are a little confusing. Is there an easier way of solving this than just looking at each combination?

Comment: Are you trying to use Burnside's lemma? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma

Answer (score 2):

This is a case of **Power Group Enumeration** with the group permuting
the slots being  the eight symmetries $G_N$ of  the $N\times N$ square
and  the group  acting on  the $Q$  colors being  the  symmetric group
$S_Q$.

The cycle indices for $G_N$  were carefully documented and computed at
the following [MSE link I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570003/).

The cycle  index of  the symmetric group  can be computed  from the
classical recurrence by Lovasz.

It  then remains  to apply  the Power  Group Enumeration  formula /
algorithm as documented at the following
[MSE link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7235/).

We  get  for  the case  of  coloring  a  square  with at  most  two
interchangeable colors
$$1, 4, 51, 4324, 2105872, 4295327872, 35184441295872,
\\ 1152921514807410688,\ldots$$
which is [OEIS A182044](https://oeis.org/A182044)
where a closed formula can be found.

For at most three colors we get the sequence
$$1, 6, 490, 901012, 17653123147, 3126972103187548, 
\\ 4985402694248850150928, 71535079589434063488162675274,
\\ 9238051838396620455005158025879826301,\ldots $$

Finally for at most four colors we get the sequence
$$1, 7, 1555, 22396971, 5864091026091, 24595658827938966187,
\\ 1650586719048786316922366635, 1772303994379887884341412962742479531,
\\ 30447950777727144129269702965544605972525918891,\ldots$$

The sequence of colorings using any number of available interchangeable colors is also quite interesting and starts
$$1, 7, 2966, 1310397193, 
\\ 579823814813639193, 477464341236883456112705749206,
\\ 1340767144321669800049265230788088027597024910,
\\ 21516767919669856366796245458194341840929552797762722429430679631,
\ldots$$

An implementation of  this algorithm is included below.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local l;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_grid :=
proc(N)
option remember;
local cind;

    if type(N, even) then
        cind :=
        1/8*(a[1]^(N^2)+3*a[2]^(N^2/2)+
             2*a[1]^N*a[2]^((N^2-N)/2) + 2*a[4]^(N^2/4));
    else
        cind :=
        1/8*(a[1]^(N^2)+4*a[1]^N*a[2]^((N^2-N)/2)+
             a[1]*a[2]^((N^2-1)/2) + 2*a[1]*a[4]^((N^2-1)/4));
    fi;

    cind;
end;

gridcols :=
proc(N, Q)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_cols, res, term_a, term_b,
    v_a, v_b, inst_a, inst_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;


    if N > 1 then
        idx_slots := pet_cycleind_grid(N);
    else
        idx_slots := [a[1]];
    fi;

    if Q > 1 then
        idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(Q);
    else
        idx_cols := [a[1]];
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for term_a in idx_slots do
        for term_b in idx_cols do
            p := 1;

            for v_a in indets(term_a) do
                len_a := op(1, v_a);
                inst_a := degree(term_a, v_a);

                q := 0;

                for v_b in indets(term_b) do
                    len_b := op(1, v_b);
                    inst_b := degree(term_b, v_b);

                    if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                        q := q + len_b*inst_b;
                    fi;
                od;

                p := p*q^inst_a;
            od;

            res := res +
            lcoeff(term_a)*lcoeff(term_b)*p;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```