# Enumeration of finite automata

Tags: combinatorics, finite-automata

> There is a nice  paper *[Enumeration of Finite  Automata](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995867911862)* by Frank Harary and Ed Palmer which presents a formula $a(n,k,m)$ for the number of finite automata with $n$ states, $k$ input symbols and $m$ output symbols. It is stated in Corollary $3$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> a(n,k,m)=\frac{1}{n!k!m!}\sum_{H_1} I(\alpha,\beta,\alpha)I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)
> \end{align*}
>   where the sum is over all permutations in $H_1=S_n^{S_n\times S_k}\times S_m^{S_n\times S_k}$ of the form $\{[(\alpha,\beta);\alpha^{-1}],[(\alpha,\beta);\gamma]\}$ with
>   \begin{align*}
> I(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)=\prod_{p=1}^n\prod_{q=1}^k\left[\sum_{s|[p,q]}sj_s(\gamma)\right]^{j_p(\alpha)j_q(\beta)\langle p,q\rangle}
> \end{align*}

Here the authors denote with $[p,q]:=\operatorname{lcm}(p,q), \langle p,q\rangle:=\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)$ and $j_p(\alpha)$ denotes the number of cycles of the permutation $\alpha$ with length $p$.

> The special case $n=k,m=1$ is already analysed and calculated for small values of $n$ in *[this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594)*, especially with focus to $n=4$.
>
> **Question:** Maybe someone could provide some computations for the general case for small values of $n,k,m$?

Comment: Asking for a clarification on the notation -- doesn't the linked-to question use $m$ for the number of states and $n$ for the number of input symbols, so that we would use $k$ for the output symbols?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Yes, the linked question does. But since the paper of Harary/Palmer is the master reference, I think it's better to stick at their notation.

Comment: I've never seen this "Power Group" notation $S_n^{S_n\times S_k}$ before, so for the benefit of anyone answering this question, I will copy it here (it's from the second page of the reference). A *power group* $B^A$ operates on a set of functions $Y^X$ from $X$ to $Y$. Given permutations $\alpha \in A, \beta \in B$,  the element $(\alpha ; \beta)\in B^A$ operates on a function $f \in X^Y$ such that $(\alpha; \beta) f(x) = \beta f(\alpha x)$.

Comment: @Marko I posted to the original question before seeing that Markus had opened a new one. I'll repost it here.

Comment: @ScottBurns You might want to consider GMP for arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  answering this  question we  refer to  the algorithm  at  the [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594/)   which  works
for the generalized  problem as well. The only  difference is that the
values that go  into the slots of the array/table  are pairs of states
and output symbols,  meaning when we transition from  a certain column
on an input  symbol corresponding to a row we  transition to the state
(first element of  the pair) and output the  symbol (second element of
the pair). The action on the slots is the simultaneous action of $\pi$
and  $\tau$ on  the rows  and columns  and we  now have  a permutation
$\sigma$ which acts on the set of output symbols and the action on the
values is  the combined action of  $\tau$ and $\sigma$ on  the state /
symbol pairs.

We get the following table for one output symbol.

```
|   1|          1|                 1|                       1|                              1|                                    1|                                           1|                                                 1|
|   3|          7|                13|                      22|                             34|                                   50|                                          70|                                                95|
|   7|         74|               638|                    4663|                          28529|                               151600|                                      713176|                                           3028727|
|  19|       1474|            118949|                 7643021|                      396979499|                          17265522590|                                646203233957|                                    21243806443115|
|  47|      41876|          42483668|             33179970333|                 20762461502595|                    10831034126757463|                         4844565331763027596|                            1896647286212566394157|
| 130|    1540696|       23524514635|         274252613077267|            2559276179593762172|              19903050866658120066632|                 132673733865643566661223817|                    773869304738817313660236854435|
| 343|   68343112|    18477841853059|     3802866637652928476|       626361440405926396941497|        85973094952794304259466151418|         10114722264843500593900485682759058|          1041247439945746392774732251877428013424|
| 951| 3540691525| 19526400231564564| 81874932562648494674439| 274724907231470170012527305235| 768186632385442429091738459545921683| 1841148232300929744056375072663778725072045| 3861169308385212945415179151162048048461447621051|
```

For two output symbols we have

```
|     1|               2|                        2|                                 3|                                          3|                                                   4|                                                           4|                                                                    5|
|     6|              44|                      226|                              1036|                                       4006|                                               13876|                                                       43186|                                                               123706|
|    22|            2038|                   142336|                           7775708|                                  341906882|                                         12592855970|                                                399366367444|                                                       11132314379998|
|   114|          176936|                238882846|                      244698934716|                            200649261017386|                                  137143648460408272|                                        80366174079209158078|                                              41217801421317353953038|
|   538|        20943790|             694540531869|                 17362195783419565|                      347256965617453111707|                           5787905149678353796143590|                               82689320232608432438262174088|                                   1033688856029644143398545746261666|
|  2800|      3108818680|         3081614657394158|            2300263170022800838590|               1373710145403734491538076692|                   683647218221456315461840833799588|                     291623393789554111334921119339297251576|                        108848103655093534827120896470552784018126133|
| 14435|    553255960308|     19368605578168164179|       510403370619400317035233276|        10760675018954199971112474584547034|          189053417206572805331242303827478007687534|           2846969183281612697167894035560332610102537605107|             37513627164757945129191686915360296965220882487348368322|
| 76312| 114776687721990| 163754994767359896315206| 175823884588034784365611422263567| 151031502945525188132621372232074129315388| 108112560585492844973667875651850996929528575835574| 66334273232261168899346826889209523621370385072001650536116| 35612941825082950044316879351953518880328546726186269125209259942000|
```

Three output symbols yield

```
|      1|                 2|                           3|                                      4|                                                5|                                                           7|                                                                     8|                                                                              10|
|      6|                74|                         775|                                   7124|                                            55668|                                                      377269|                                                               2255068|                                                                        12102178|
|     29|              7623|                     1804128|                              329641077|                                      48317584819|                                               5910777204447|                                                       620630699132987|                                                               57098016161377374|
|    190|           1501516|                 10322146155|                         53512221536494|                               221968136483832014|                                       767306804276224740828|                                             2273639672252875423729778|                                                    5895263464882668948056075498|
|   1289|         401371270|             101367856946674|                   19243544529701850104|                        2922627429145967591227933|                              369897467120287921148106491100|                                   40127586921742103692252419866530400|                                        3809020901470314640315364328599642887506|
|   9673|      134138227473|         1518024410618449355|             12907594258334064169919121|                 87803188849193004851359368791756|                     497730359833453928180319002991414602093|                        2418417068028280199534213597754694851805840225|                           10281969996512134071147543063509604282591387558257520|
|  73604|    53725010241266|     32201676604966459555889|       14499308203534486200843433873288|         5222906915046943511008193569385565417541|           1567819635143439097415728431946215896270059293161|             403397426941463986598664115278880491308873007636372427413|               90819310744609116970288225981171645606992548661728301980002516662|
| 573442| 25081227120200634| 918865057207831149035535828| 25285803348327743049043999665003927370| 556668502782671968664754976635618690023788914186| 10212576716712592462402577334011641314012112279662417473469| 160593227242102911238351158110065456181421151497935704882980552606514| 2209668743041973325985756217800328983151637526070225333484395817216844313778044|
```

Four symbols yield

```
|       1|                  2|                              3|                                         5|                                                     6|                                                                9|                                                                          11|                                                                                     15|
|       6|                 81|                           1183|                                     17320|                                                223743|                                                          2527953|                                                                    25100642|                                                                              222144431|
|      29|              11676|                        6064606|                                2593640209|                                          897009602752|                                                  259029607981273|                                                           64163314527895517|                                                                   13915354324987224434|
|     209|            3831148|                    81573276196|                          1334647986999812|                                  17493019379544106141|                                         191083931326433751661244|                                                1789145512052234025354299479|                                                       14658245204843197745963032946030|
|    1605|         1790644262|               1896670209705424|                    1517048789183286280242|                           970906913413864886205472630|                                517817738821504564293534451239523|                                     236717123156531446119639354041331039161|                                           94687056373953999303903668799913187496263156|
|   14581|      1059379897194|           67316410303471722434|              3215992447007150335848738654|                  122917096383192644964591012637376201|                      3914970565374711299589044295533654728633307|                         106880364202506644619748019682746095700393900152769|                             2553144552899651934745530164746582340956543973128820263056|
|  139393|    753537775187942|      3384772964731425916075399|       11417522742490309099171117430032545|          30811161705715253062014503052903675566658545|            69288800372821565423720577304077855202305583626701885|             133558404360787903168869516536280931557107488047811301767090944|               225261750393971075099732774525570356293879964632402213718679044305894097|
| 1396571| 625251791124395555| 228938436067723951049495991006| 62929794221715160999635636523327894882612| 13838407708142508413727196626725814975774777251143465| 2535915030456565177161444959970701001632828430350354446662490458| 398324009007397248996962807526047717969141597988514641606768498289421689877| 54745234941096457415294245370001308972451724232455240696557887565208148810995582605398|
```

Five yield

```
|       1|                   2|                               3|                                            5|                                                        7|                                                                   10|                                                                               13|                                                                                           18|
|       6|                  81|                            1283|                                        23718|                                                   427097|                                                              7038183|                                                                        103821898|                                                                                   1372476565|
|      29|               12621|                         9875766|                                   7694431189|                                            5108729338005|                                                     2866744631627614|                                                              1383444387175373624|                                                                        584738631310521555854|
|     209|             5269634|                    242293771832|                             9508729532667775|                                    303537782294910006324|                                            8092008307288214998320242|                                                   184959457244832433282602143175|                                                           3699331066099122391214267900044654|
|    1652|          3522483774|               10830193709142911|                      26326043763404282897041|                            51400728418762283743166947873|                                  83657888529920202329649049898106090|                                       116710057646947398301738658574346204631684|                                             142468411615177769332030145694979476640229799189|
|   15851|       3145805694347|           748102205731495912974|               136208975222504119847429651282|                   19858370962230255015514418124978318079|                       2412787002750586428934439397030434799264061139|                           251274509502830170033287481345380174207693056359521218|                               22897389793260955643229220128574252798224672181928261140465132|
|  166704|    3451400880452119|      73411241836287162439679965|        1180551376563438246848941889675139885|          15191078168438817387019547141066538853359987716|            162897187467367310343607416594982652886027395559664704867|              1497241493787657622590696899117249253525915361372369634716838093562|                12041433120029892610323311791551075975557111745695889862014376128073109032711|
| 1903565| 4453493876743114141| 9696353154834682640039652745383| 15885725788645815939897203091966549890622620| 20821721985157272922019024288021084022442430164588852951| 22742872566990523157952024381064067346859577618809430167348089260678| 21292527088890116346521008056915214793265230093299707297080802600716512185635775| 17442838191172723332310678848004599133452884005515399679140805741625547114446168989072880538|
```

Finally we get for six symbols

```
|       1|                    2|                                 3|                                             5|                                                          7|                                                                      11|                                                                                  14|                                                                                               20|
|       6|                   81|                              1296|                                         25462|                                                     538398|                                                                11293138|                                                                           222523395|                                                                                       4028465835|
|      29|                12695|                          11328242|                                   12588216476|                                             13507531099557|                                                       12816676023294742|                                                                10610435880654869474|                                                                           7727294095780485593467|
|     209|              5635034|                      396518228841|                             29902254119865429|                                     1947536351902062154396|                                             107300432454566001311927042|                                                     5082116300041019725568491696927|                                                             210740137620013511032529954013222997|
|    1652|           4452248665|                 28661573376513712|                      168916250895768873373125|                             817701868164546859278494745163|                                   3309982213851389919369842502624515185|                                        11489588802579132510260340618793545674029229|                                               34899323818332948931809633587657800749959429140381|
|   15981|        5147747713851|            3350282292788028229116|               1806224092274722460193800299488|                    785710893213334594665452752490935409600|                        285033249600409431428643990739291312182972084132|                            88635922473731155883430561365483225722614035385062387241|                                24117625609927898779221726509298149056270088412428821435055351917|
|  171494|     7721337186134447|       564461055370558962491069562|        32440112974696247296439224174402635608|          1495496356773389913366753876131348301821086183629|             57461231472727120738649283370058285613319924784137652332510|              1892438067444572851650149500498661434054764424790064535313952779756847|                 54535174475104423211660022224834911399436311980199332329136348183225443895408945|
| 2041940| 14003166710753529537| 128580139323392617149472430498611| 905045555050578843422814928359489284108944076| 5100536012710000997786910449314715054126988193344281363091| 23954874543703392448557828429937283387539096055257084732285733625757877| 96433013296267950226465899688337115485213562485757881838921103460239405763926814829| 339676614862729029614552301296020122485910436927008569295805654935518977116532247635480871741432|
```

The Maple code for this was as follows.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
local p, s;
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;

cycles_prod :=
proc(cyca, cycb)
local ca, cb, lena, lenb, res, vlcm;

    res := 1;

    for ca in cyca do
        lena := op(1, ca);

        for cb in cycb do
            lenb := op(1, cb);

            vlcm := lcm(lena, lenb);
            res := res*a[vlcm]^(lena*lenb/vlcm);
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;


automaton :=
proc(N, M, K)
option remember;
local idx_slots, idx_cols, idx_syms, res, a, b, c, sim, flat_sim,
    sym, flat_sym, flat_a, flat_b, flat_c,
    cyc_a, cyc_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if N > 1 then
        idx_slots := pet_cycleind_symm(N);
    else
        idx_slots := [a[1]];
    fi;

    if M > 1 then
        idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(M);
    else
        idx_cols := [a[1]];
    fi;

    if K > 1 then
        idx_syms := pet_cycleind_symm(K);
    else
        idx_syms := [a[1]];
    fi;


    res := 0;

    for a in idx_slots do
        flat_a := pet_flatten_term(a);
        for b in idx_cols do
            flat_b := pet_flatten_term(b);

            sim := cycles_prod(flat_a[2], flat_b[2]);
            flat_sim := pet_flatten_term(sim);

            for c in idx_syms do
                flat_c := pet_flatten_term(c);

                sym := cycles_prod(flat_b[2], flat_c[2]);
                flat_sym := pet_flatten_term(sym);

                p := 1;

                for cyc_a in flat_sim[2] do
                    len_a := op(1, cyc_a);
                    q := 0;

                    for cyc_b in flat_sym[2] do
                        len_b := op(1, cyc_b);

                        if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                            q := q + len_b;
                        fi;
                    od;

                    p := p*q;
                od;

                res := res +
                p*flat_a[1]*flat_b[1]*flat_c[1];
            od;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;


output :=
proc(MXN, MXM, K)
local data, N, M, fd, fname, width;

    data := table();

    for N to MXN do
        data[N] := table();

        for M to MXM do
            data[N][M] := automaton(M, N, K);
        od;
    od;

    fname := sprintf("automata-%d-%d-%d.txt", MXN, MXM, K);
    fd := fopen(fname, WRITE);

    for N to MXN do
        fprintf(fd, "|");
        for M to MXM do
            width := nops(convert(data[MXN][M], base, 10));
            fprintf(fd, "% *d|", width+1, data[N][M]);
        od;
        fprintf(fd, "\n");
    od;

    fclose(fd);
end;
```

Comment: Great answer! Many thanks for your qick and valuable support! (+1)

Comment: @MarkusScheuer  These sequences are now in the OEIS draft queue having tags A277839 to A277844. I hope we might get a contribution using Mathematica, or possibly GAP or SAGE. Thank you for your collaboration in this problem which I in fact overlooked when it first appeared.

Comment: Great Marko! Thanks for preparing everything!

Comment: @Marko Excellent work. I have done these calculations and got the same results independently

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: You might find *[this identity at MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/253703/integral-of-a-sin-omial-coefficients-binomial)* interesting.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer I just learned that the sequences from this post were accepted into the OEIS. Congratulations! Unfortunately there was no alternate software (I had pointed to Mathematica and GAP), It would be an advantage to implement the formulae directly from the paper (i.e. without consulting the posted code), thereby providing independent verification.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Good news! Many thanks, Marko! I'm pretty sure, your results are sound. Best regards,

Comment: I did not explain it properly -- sometimes an OEIS adminstrator will add a Mathematica / GAP program when a sequence first appears in the draft queue. This was not the case this time. That is what I was refering to, I too am confident that the results are sound.

Answer (score 1):

Below are tables for $a(N,K,M)$ for values $\le 5$ where

$N = $ number of states, $K = $ number of inputs, $M = $ number of outputs.

Note that if we fix $N$ and $K$ and let $M$ increase, this eventually becomes independent of $M$. Once $M$ is sufficiently large to cover any possible equivalence over the edges of the state transtion graph, there is no gain from increasing it.

So two interesting questions:

What is the terminal $M$ for each choice of $(N,K)$? I.e. calculate
$$
M^*(N,K) := m^*: a(N,K,m) = a(N,K,m^*)\ \ \  \forall \ m>m^*
$$
What are the values of $a(N,K,M^*(N,K))$?

```
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| M=2 |   | K    |            |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     |   | 1    | 2          | 3               | 4               | 5               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| N   | 1 | 1    | 2          | 2               | 3               | 3               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 2 | 6    | 44         | 226             | 1036            | 4006            |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 3 | 22   | 2038       | 142336          | 7775708         | 341906882       |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 4 | 114  | 176936     | 238882846       | 244698934716    | 200649261017386 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 5 | 538  | 20943790   | 694540531869    | 1.35E+015       |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     |   |      |            |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| M=3 |   | K    |            |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     |   | 1    | 2          | 3               | 4               | 5               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| N   | 1 | 1    | 2          | 3               | 4               | 5               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 2 | 6    | 75         | 775             | 7124            | 55668           |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 3 | 29   | 7623       | 1804128         | 329641077       | 48317584819     |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 4 | 190  | 1501516    | 10322146155     | 53512221536494  |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 5 | 1289 | 401371270  | 101367856946674 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     |   |      |            |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| M=4 |   | K    |            |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     |   | 1    | 2          | 3               | 4               | 5               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| N   | 1 | 1    | 2          | 3               | 5               | 6               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 2 | 6    | 81         | 1183            | 17320           | 223743          |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 3 | 29   | 11676      | 6064606         | 2593640209      | 897009602752    |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 4 | 209  | 3831148    | 81573276196     | 248097408553    |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 5 | 1605 | 1790644262 |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     |   |      |            |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| M=5 |   | K    |            |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     |   | 1    | 2          | 3               | 4               | 5               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| N   | 1 | 1    | 2          | 3               | 5               | 7               |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 2 | 6    | 81         | 1283            | 23718           | 427097          |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 3 | 29   | 12621      | 9875766         | 7694431189      | 5108729338005   |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 4 | 209  | 5269634    | 242293771832    | 167930305528968 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|     | 5 | 1652 | 3522483774 |                 |                 |                 |
+-----+---+------+------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: We should now verify that these answers match. I could not find any differences except for $A(4,4,5)$ where you have $167930305528968$ and I have $9508729532667775.$ I also suggest you compute the results for six output symbols and compare them to what I posted. We can submit to the OEIS if all checks are cleared.

Comment: @ScottBurns: Good work! When both answers match the result is worth to become a sequence in OEIS. (+1)

Comment: The difference is almost certainly due to overflow. I've only coded for 64-bit integers. Do I really want to use gmp? No as it's horrid in C - but I coud compile with g++. And it will fill out the rest of the table...

Comment: I was thinking about my question about convergence. It's trivial that $M^* \le NK$ as that's the number of edges in any state graph. Are there any instances where it's strictly less?