# What is the number of possibilities of grouping objects

Tags: combinatorics

I do have $n\times m$ objects $o_{ij}$. I'm looking for the number of possible groupings these objects. A valid grouping must not have any two object of the same row in one group. For example in the case $3\times 2$, a valid grouping is
 $\{\{o_{11}, o_{22}, o_{31}\}, \{o_{12}, o_{32}\}, \{o_{21}\}\}$. 
An invalid grouping is $\{\{o_{11}, o_{12}, o_{31}\}, \{o_{22}, o_{32}\}, \{o_{21}\}\}$, since $o_{11}$ and $o_{12}$ must not be in the same group. What is the number of valid groupings of $n\times m$ such objects?

Comment: This appears to be a "non-flat" partition. See this answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200646/non-flat-partitions-of-a-set/200650, and also Chapter 4 of G. Peccati and M. Taqqu. Wiener Chaos: Moments, Cumulants and Diagrams: A survey with Computer Implementation. Bocconi & Springer Series. Springer, 2011.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of **Power Group Enumeration** with the group acting on
the slots being the  trivial group containing the identity permutation
on $n\times m$  elements and the symmetric group  acting on the values
going  into the slots  being the  symmetric group  $S_q.$ Here  a slot
receives as its value the number of  the set it goes into  and the set
identifiers are  being permuted by  the symmetric group and  we obtain
set partitions into at most $q$ sets.

We evidently require a classification  of the permutations in $S_q$ by
the number of fixed points. We do  the case $m=1$ first and should get
Bell  numbers. Observe  that the  combinatorial class  of permutations
with fixed points marked is

$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{=1}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=2}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=3}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \textsc{CYC}_{=4}(\mathcal{Z})
+ \cdots).$$

This gives the generating function
$$G(z, u) = 
\exp\left(uz + \frac{z^2}{2} +
\frac{z^3}{3} +
\frac{z^4}{4} +
\frac{z^5}{5} + \cdots\right)$$

which is
$$G(z, u) =
\exp\left((u-1)z + \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)
\\ = \frac{\exp((u-1)z)}{1-z}
= \exp(uz) \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}.$$

Therefore the number of permutations  in $S_q$ having $p$ fixed points
is given by

$$q! [z^q] \frac{z^p}{p!} \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
= \frac{q!}{p!} [z^{q-p}] \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
= \frac{q!}{p!} \sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Write it like this

$${q\choose p} (q-p)! \sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

to see  immediately that we choose  the $p$ fixed points  from the $q$
possibilities and combine them with a derangement of the rest.

Now in the Power Group Construction we place copies of cycles from the
group permuting  the values on the  cycles of the  group permuting the
slots, consisting  of fixed points only  in the present  example. If a
permutation from $S_q$ contains $p$ fixed points we get a contribution
of $p^{n\times  m}$ which  is $p^n.$ This  yields (the term  for $p=0$
produces a zero value and may be omitted; the $q!$ was canceled by the
average from the cycle index $Z(S_q)$)

$$\sum_{p=1}^q \frac{p^n}{p!} 
\sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

Continuing with  the sanity check we  should get Bell  numbers when we
put $n=q$ (partition of $[q]$ into at most $q$ sets). We get

$$\sum_{p=1}^q \frac{p^q}{p!} 
\sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

which yields

$$1, 2, 5, 15, 52, 203, 877, 4140, 21147, 115975, 678570, 
\\ 4213597, 27644437, 190899322, \ldots$$

which is indeed [OEIS A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110), the sequence
of Bell numbers.

Continuing with PGE we now treat the general case where the $m$ values
in  the $n$  rows may  not occur  together for  a contribution  of (we
choose a set  of unique fixed points -- no duplicates  -- from the $p$
available ones and place them on the cycles, also fixed points, of the
single  slot permutation corresponding  to that  row, the  $n\times m$
slots having been divided into $n$ blocks of size $m$):

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
m!^n \sum_{p=1}^{n\times m} {p\choose m}^n \frac{1}{p!} 
\sum_{k=0}^{n\times m-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.}$$

We get e.g. for $m=2$ the sequence

$$1, 7, 87, 1657, 43833, 1515903, 65766991, 
\\ 3473600465, 218310229201, 16035686850327, \ldots$$

which  is [OEIS  A020556](https://oeis.org/A020556) and  for  $m=3$ we
obtain

$$1, 34, 2971, 513559, 149670844, 66653198353, 42429389528215,
\\ 36788942253042556, 41888564490333642283, 60862147523250910055785,
\ldots$$

which  is  [OEIS  A069223](https://oeis.org/A069223)  and  has  highly
relevant data.

**Remark.** We  use the follwing method  for the proof  that we get
Bell numbers when $m=1$: starting from

$$\sum_{k=0}^n {n\brace k} x^{\underline{k}} = x^n$$

we find

$$\sum_{p=1}^q \frac{p^q}{p!} 
\sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
= \sum_{p=1}^q \frac{1}{p!}
\sum_{r=0}^q {q\brace r} {p\choose r} r! 
\sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

This becomes

$$\sum_{r=0}^q {q\brace r}
\sum_{p=r}^q \frac{1}{(p-r)!} \sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}.$$

We have it if we can show  the coefficient on ${q\brace r}$ is one. We
get

$$\sum_{p=r}^q \frac{1}{(p-r)!} \sum_{k=0}^{q-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
= \sum_{p=0}^{q-r} \frac{1}{p!} 
\sum_{k=0}^{q-p-r} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}
= \sum_{p=0}^l \frac{1}{p!} 
\sum_{k=0}^{l-p} \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

with $l$ a positive number. Continuing

$$\sum_{p=0}^l \frac{1}{p!} [z^{l-p}] \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
= \sum_{p=0}^l \frac{1}{p!} [z^l] z^p \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
= [z^l] \sum_{p=0}^l \frac{1}{p!} z^p \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}$$

As we are extracting the coefficient on $[z^l]$ we may extend the sum
to infinity without any additional contributions and get

$$[z^l] \sum_{p\ge 0} \frac{1}{p!} z^p \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z}
= [z^l] \frac{\exp(-z)}{1-z} \exp(z) = [z^l] \frac{1}{1-z} = 1$$

as claimed.

The  following  Maple  code  was  used to  investigate  these  numbers
(somewhat optimized).

```
X :=
proc(n, m)

    (m!)^n*add(binomial(p,m)^n
               *1/p!*add((-1)^k/k!, k=0..n*m-p),
               p=1..n*m);
end;

ENUM :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local src, recurse, res; 

    src :=
    [seq(seq([A[p], B[q]], q=1..m), p=1..n)];

    res := 0;

    recurse :=
    proc(pos, spart, len)
        local idx, nxt, var;

        if pos > n*m then
            res := res + 1;
            return;
        fi;

        nxt := src[pos]; var := op(1, nxt) * op(2, nxt);

        for idx to len do
            if degree(spart[idx], op(1, nxt)) = 0 
            then
                spart[idx] := spart[idx] * var;

                recurse(pos + 1, spart, len);

                spart[idx] := spart[idx] / var;
            fi;
        od;

        spart[len + 1] := var;
        recurse(pos + 1, spart, len + 1);
        spart[len + 1] := 1;
    end;

    recurse(1, Array([seq(1, q=1..n*m)]), 0);

    res;
end;

CHECK :=
proc()
    {seq(ENUM(n, 1) - X(n, 1), n=1..10),
     seq(ENUM(n, 2) - X(n, 2), n=1..6),
     seq(ENUM(n, 3) - X(n, 3), n=1..4),
     seq(ENUM(n, 4) - X(n, 4), n=1..3),
     seq(ENUM(n, 5) - X(n, 5), n=1..2)};
end;
```

PGE      recently      appeared       at      this      [MSE      link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540602/)   and  this  [MSE
link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594/).

**Addendum.**  Here is the code with   some    superfluous   variables
optimized out.

```
ENUM :=
proc(n, m)
    option remember;
    local src, recurse, res; 

    src :=
    [seq(seq(A[p], q=1..m), p=1..n)];

    res := 0;

    recurse :=
    proc(pos, spart, len)
        local idx, nxt;

        if pos > n*m then
            res := res + 1;
            return;
        fi;

        nxt := src[pos];

        for idx to len do
            if degree(spart[idx], nxt) = 0 
            then
                spart[idx] := spart[idx] * nxt;
                recurse(pos + 1, spart, len);
                spart[idx] := spart[idx] / nxt;
            fi;
        od;

        spart[len + 1] := nxt;
        recurse(pos + 1, spart, len + 1);
        spart[len + 1] := 1;
    end;

    recurse(1, Array([seq(1, q=1..n*m)]), 0);

    res;
end;
```

Comment: This will take some time to digest, but this is an excellent answer.

Comment: Could you potentially explain further the opening paragraph? E.g. what are the slots. You mean you have the set and groups, and there is a set of functions between them?

Comment: In **PGE** we have two groups, one  of them acting on a sequence of
slots permuting the slots and  another acting on the objects that
are  distributed into  these  slots.  We seek  the  count of  the
orbits. In the  present case the $n\times m$ slots  are not being
permuted  at all  so the  group contains  the identity  only. The
objects going into  the slots are the $n\times  m$ identifiers of
the possible sets, which have  the symmetric group acting on them
with cycle index $Z(S_{n\times m}).$

Comment: (...) We then cover the $n$ rows with fixed points in the terms of $Z(S_{n\times m})$, choosing for a permutation with $p$ fixed points $m$ unique values per row because these may not be in the same set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a graph coloring technique. For the $i^{\text{th}}$ row of $o_{ij}$, form a $j$-clique. So for $m=2$, form a collection of $n$ 2-cliques, and call the collection $g$. For $m=2$, this is a [ladder rung graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LadderRungGraph.html) $nP_2$.

Now, with $G$ the number of different groups you wish to use, color the vertices of the disjoint set of cliques with the numbers ${1,2,\dots,G}$, without coloring adjacent vertices the same color.

For $n=2,3,\dots$, the following chromatic polynomial $\chi_g(k,n)$ gives the number of distinct colorings of $nP_2$ with $k$ or fewer colors. The second parameter simply defines the order of the ladder rung graph. These polynomials are:

$$\chi_g(k,2)=k^2-k$$
$$\chi_g(k,3)=k^4-2 k^3+k^2$$
$$\chi_g(k,4)=k^6-3 k^5+3 k^4-k^3$$
$$\chi_g(k,5)=k^4 - 4 k^5 + 6 k^6 - 4 k^7 + k^8$$

and so on for $n>5$. You want to count the number of distinct groupings (topological enumeration), and so, to quote [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344622/graph-coloring-with-exactly-k-colors/3345062#3345062):

> Let $S \subseteq \{1,2,3,4\}=S_0$, and let $P_S$ be the number of
>   proper colorings of $G$ that use either $S$ or a subset of $S$. Let
>   $P'_S$ be the number of proper colorings of $S$ that use *all* of $S$
>   ie., every color of $S$ is used in the coloring.
>
> Then by Inclusion-Exclusion:
>
> $$P'_{S_0} = P_{S_0} -\sum_{S: |S|=3} P_S + \sum_{S: |S|=2} P_S - \sum_{S: |S|=1} P_S$$
>
> or to use the notation in the statement of the problem, where
>   $P'(G,k)$ is the number of colourings of $G$ that use *all* $k$
>   colors:
>
> $$P'(G,4) = P(G,4)-4P(G,3)+6P(G,2)-4P(G,1)$$

Using Mathematica, one can verify this, comparing with the result given by Power Group enumeration (in Marko Riedel's answer). With a ladder rung graph $nP_2$ denoted `G[n]` (refering to the case $m=2$), and the chromatic polynomial defined as follows:

```
G[n_] := Graph[Range[n], Table[i <-> i + 1, {i, 1, n, 2}]];
h[k_, n_] := ChromaticPolynomial[G[n], k];
```

then we have the number of distinct groupings with 4, 3 and 2 groups, given by

```
1/4! (h[4, 4] - 4 h[3, 4] + 6 h[2, 4] - 4 h[1, 4])
1/3! (h[3, 4] - 3 h[2, 4] + 3 h[1, 4])
1/2! (h[2, 4] - 2 h[1, 4])
```

which gives

> 1
>
> 4
>
> 2

which sum to 7. The next term is

```
1/6! (h[6, 6] - 6 h[5, 6] + 15 h[4, 6] - 20 h[3, 6] + 15 h[2, 6] - 6 h[1, 6])
1/5! (h[5, 6] - 5 h[4, 6] + 10 h[3, 6] - 10 h[2, 6] + 5 h[1, 6])
1/4! (h[4, 6] - 4 h[3, 6] + 6 h[2, 6] - 4 h[1, 6])
1/3! (h[3, 6] - 3 h[2, 6] + 3 h[1, 6])
1/2! (h[2, 6] - 2 h[1, 6])
```

> 1
>
> 12
>
> 38
>
> 32
>
> 4

whose sum is 87, which gives the next term in the list.

Also, the next term

```
1/8! (h[8, 8] - 8 h[7, 8] + 28 h[6, 8] - 56 h[5, 8] + 70 h[4, 8] - 
   56 h[3, 8] + 28 h[2, 8] - 8 h[1, 8])

1/7! (h[7, 8] - 7 h[6, 8] + 21 h[5, 8] - 35 h[4, 8] + 35 h[3, 8] - 
   21 h[2, 8] + 7 h[1, 8])

1/6! (h[6, 8] - 6 h[5, 8] + 15 h[4, 8] - 20 h[3, 8] + 15 h[2, 8] - 
   6 h[1, 8])

1/5! (h[5, 8] - 5 h[4, 8] + 10 h[3, 8] - 10 h[2, 8] + 5 h[1, 8])

1/4! (h[4, 8] - 4 h[3, 8] + 6 h[2, 8] - 4 h[1, 8])

1/3! (h[3, 8] - 3 h[2, 8] + 3 h[1, 8])

1/2! (h[2, 8] - 2 h[1, 8])
```

> 1
>
> 24
>
> 188
>
> 576
>
> 652
>
> 208
>
> 8

whose sum is 1657.

The whole sequence is meant to be $$1,7,87,1657,43833,1515903,65766991,3473600465,218310229201,\dots$$

which is given in the OEIS [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C7%2C87&language=english&go=Search).

Similarly, this works for $m>2$. For example, $m=3$ gives

$$ 1, 34, 2971, 513559, 149670844, 66653198353, 42429389528215 \dots$$

which is given [here](https://oeis.org/A069223).