# Counting sets containing unlabelled sequences of total cardinality n

Tags: general-topology, combinatorics

How do I count all sets $S$ containing sequences which contain values of an alphabet $A$ where:

$\displaystyle\quad\sum_{x\in S} |x| = n$

And two sets are equivalent under permutation of alphabet symbols. eg: $\{[1,2],[1]\} = \{[2,9],[2]\}.$)

$n=1$ has only a single option: $\{[0]\}$, for $n=2$ there are 4:
$\{[0,0]\},\{[0],[0]\},\{[0,1]\},\{[0],[1]\}$

$n=3$ has 13 ($[0,1,0]$ notated as $010$):
$\{000\},\{0,00\},\{0,0,0\},\{001\},\{0,01\},\{0,11\},\{0,0,1\},\{010\},\{0,10\},\{011\},\{012\},\{0,12\},\{0,1,2\}$

And so forth, the first couple values are: $1,4,13,57,252,1322,7361$.

I haven't really gotten anywhere beyond that, but the amount of sets with a single sequence of length $n$ is equal to the $n$th Bell number. The amount of divisions for each sequence of length $n$ is $2^{n-1}$, but at that point you count sets that are equivalent under a permutation of $A$ and I'm not sure how many are equivalent.

Comment: Is the cardinality of the alphabet known? Is it independent of $n$ or is it always at least $n$ or something similar? Your $n=2$ set solution contains the set $\{[0],[0]\}$. How is that set different from just the set $\{[0]\}$ that already appears for $n=1$?

Comment: Ah you're right, it's a multiset I suppose, I'm sorry. The size of alphabet is <= n because otherwise you could choose a permutation of the alphabet that "compacts" it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interesting problem may be solved by **Power Group Enumeration**.
The  challenging part  is that  the sequence  is almost  impossible to
compute  beyond the  initial  five terms  by  total enumeration.   The
computation is done by a  particularly simple form of PGE as presented
by  e.g.    Harary  and  Palmer  and  (in   a  different  publication)
Fripertinger.  The present case does not involve generating functions.
and can in fact be done with Burnside's lemma. The scenario is that we
have  two groups,  one permuting  the slots  and another  the elements
being placed  into these slots. The  easy part is that  $n$ letters go
into the slots and these letters have the symmetric group $S_n$ acting
on them. What  is somewhat more challenging is the  cycle index of the
group permuting  the slots but  only moderately so.  We  implement the
concept of a  multiset by partitioning the $n$  slots according to one
of the $p(n)$  partitions of $n.$ (These are  not combinations. We use
combinations  in the  total enumeration  routine but  not  here.)  The
partition corresponds to a multiset  of sequences where the lengths of
the  sequences  are  given  by  the constitutents  of  the  partition.
E.g. the  partition $2+2+3$ of  $n=7$ corresponds to two  sequences of
length two  and one of  length three. It  is now easy to  describe the
action of the  group acting on the slots (there is  one such group for
each partition): it permutes the  $q$ constituents of the partition of
the  same length  $m$ aocording  to the  symmetric group  $S_q$.  This
means it must  move these slots in parallel   since the sequences form
inseparable  blocks.   Therefore a  cycle  from  $S_q$  must have  its
variables  $a_p$ replaced by  $a_p^m$ as  there is  one copy  of $a_p$
moving the first  elements of the blocks of  equal length, another for
the  second elements  and so  on until  the copy  of $a_p$  that moves
elements    at   position   $m.$    These   movements    must   happen
simultaneously. We  then obtain the desired  cycle index corresponding
to a given partition by combining  the action on sequences of the same
length  for   all  lengths   that  appear  (multiplication   of  cycle
indices).  This effectively implements  the concept  of a  multiset of
sequences.   We  can then  compute  the  number  of configurations  by
Burnside's lemma which says to average the number of assignments fixed
by  the elements  of the  power  group.  But  this number  is easy  to
compute.   Suppose  we  have  a  permutation $\alpha$  from  the  slot
permutation  group $Q$  and a  permutation $\beta$  from $S_n.$  If we
place  the appropriate  number of  complete, directed  and consecutive
copies of  a cycle  from $\beta$  on a cycle  from $\alpha$  then this
assignment is fixed under the power group action for $(\alpha,\beta)$,
and this is possible iff the  length of the cycle from $\beta$ divides
the length  of the  cycle from $\alpha$.   The process yields  as many
assignments as the  length of the cycle from  $\beta.$ In what follows
we  have implemented  one  extra optimization  which  was absent  from
earlier contributions like  those in the links shown  at the end. This
is  that instead  of flattening  $\alpha$  and $\beta$  into lists  of
single  cycles and  iterating over  these singletons  to  discover the
number of coverings of a cycle from $\alpha$ by cycles from $\beta$ we
have  made use  of the  fact  that the  existence of  a covering  only
depends on the lengths of the two cycles and hence we may process sets
of  cycles  having  the  same   length  all  at  once,  a  significant
savings. This  is achieved by  multiplying the number of  coverings by
the number of cycles of the same  length in $\beta$ as the one used in
the covering  and raising the  number of coverings to  the appropriate
power that  represents the number of  cycles of the  current length in
$\alpha$,  which reflects  the fact  that  we may  freely combine  any
admissible covering of a cycle from $\alpha$ with any other.

We now  share the  results and  the program that  was used  to compute
them. The sequence goes

$$1, 4, 13, 57, 252, 1322, 7361, 45057, 294392, 2054394, 15172872,
\\ 118175823, 966300054, 8268640847, 73825951226, 
\\ 686049132714, 6620780612228, \ldots$$

This is the PGE code that was used.

```
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_termA :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), [op(1,v), d]];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;

pet_cycleind_mset :=
proc(msdata)
local msrep, res, cycs, num, slist;

    msrep := convert(msdata, `multiset`);

    res := 1;

    for cycs in msrep do
        num := op(2, cycs);
        slist := [seq(a[q]=a[q]^op(1, cycs), q=1..num)];

        res := res
        *subs(slist, pet_cycleind_symm(num));

    od;

    expand(res);
end;

set_seq :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local part, idx_slots, idx_syms, res, a, b,
    flat_a, flat_b, cyc_a, cyc_b, len_a, len_b, p, q;

    if n > 1 then
        idx_syms := pet_cycleind_symm(n);
    else
        idx_syms := [a[1]];
    fi;

    res := 0;

    for part in partition(n) do
        idx_slots := pet_cycleind_mset(part);

        if not type(idx_slots, `+`) then
            idx_slots := [idx_slots];
        fi;

        for a in idx_slots do
            flat_a := pet_flatten_termA(a);

            for b in idx_syms do
                flat_b := pet_flatten_termA(b);

                p := 1;
                for cyc_a in flat_a[2] do
                    len_a := op(1, cyc_a);
                    q := 0;

                    for cyc_b in flat_b[2] do
                        len_b := op(1, cyc_b);

                        if len_a mod len_b = 0 then
                            q := q + len_b*op(2, cyc_b);
                        fi;
                    od;

                    p := p*q^op(2, cyc_a);
                od;

                res := res + p*flat_a[1]*flat_b[1];
            od;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

set_seq_enum :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local orbits, orbit, ind, slist, perm, part, comb, item,
    entlst, sofar, sb, len;

    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    slist := [];

    for perm in permute(n) do
        slist :=
        [op(slist), [seq(q-1=perm[q]-1, q=1..n)]];
    od;

    orbits := table();

    for ind from n^n to 2*n^n-1 do
        item := convert(ind, base, n)[1..n];

        for part in partition(n) do
            for comb in permute(part) do
                entlst := []; sofar := 0;

                for len in comb do
                    entlst :=
                    [op(entlst), item[1+sofar..len+sofar]];
                    sofar := sofar + len;
                od;

                orbit := [];

                for sb in slist do
                    orbit :=
                    [op(orbit), sort(subs(sb, entlst))];
                od;

                orbits[convert(orbit, `set`)] := 1;
            od;
        od;
    od;

    # nops([indices(orbits, `nolist`)]);
    numelems(orbits);
end;
```

PGE      recently      appeared       at      this      [MSE      link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540602/)   and  this  [MSE
link II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594/).