# Applying Burnside's Lemma to translations

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I want to know how to calculate the number of unique arrangements of $T$ different types of objects on an $M \times N$ grid, not counting "toroidal translations". That is, translations where the objects pushed of the edge of the grid reappear on the other side. For a specific example let's use $T = 2, M = 2, N = 3$ since it is simple but non-trivial and conveniently enough we can use [Unicode braille characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille#Unicode) to represent arrangements.

Here's some examples of "toroidal translations" applied to `⠝`:

- Up: `⠮`
- Down: `⠳`
- Right (the same as Left): `⠫`

When looking for techniques to solve this problems I came across Burnside's Lemma, primarily through [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdDF7_vfLcE) but I'm having some trouble applying it to this case.

Here's what I've tried so far:

There are $2^6 = 64$ possible arrangements, so that's 64 fixed points for the "do nothing" translation. When $M=2$ a rightward translation will always be the same as a leftward one so we only need to consider one of those. In order for a rightward translation to not affect the arrangement the columns must match so there are $2^3 = 8$ fixed points (, `⠉`,⠀`⠒` ... `⠶`, and `⠿`). Regarding upward and downward translations, two upward translations are the same as one downward one and vice versa, so we only need to consider two different cases. In both of those cases, the rows must match so we have two sets of $2^2 = 4$ fixed points, (, `⠇`,⠀`⠸`, and `⠿`.) Applying the lemma we get $\frac{64 + 8 + 4 + 4}{4} = \frac{80}{4} = 20$.

But then I tried finding the orbits by checking manually to make sure I had done this correctly, and I was only able to find $14$ different ones!

Here are some representatives of each orbit I found, paired to show some symmetry:

- /`⠿`
- `⠁`/`⠾`
- `⠃`/`⠼`
- `⠉`/`⠶`
- `⠊`/`⠵`
- `⠋`/`⠴`
- `⠇`
- `⠕`

So it seems like I must have either missed some fixed points or that set of orbits is incomplete. Can someone spot my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we have here is the cyclic  group of order $M$ acting on the rows
and of order  $N$ acting on the  columns. We may apply  Burnside if we
succeed in computing the cycle index  of this action, call it $Z(Q_{M,
N}).$ Now the cycle index of the cyclic group of order $M$ is given by

$$Z(C_M) = \frac{1}{M} \sum_{d|M} \varphi(d) a_d^{M/d}.$$

We therefore  require the factorization  into cycles of  a permutation
with   factorization  $a_d^{M/d}$   and  another   with  factorization
$b_f^{N/f}$  acting  simultaneously  on   the  row-column  pairs  that
identify the  slots of the  matrix, with the  first one acting  on the
rows  and the  second one  on  the columns.   The combination  creates
$d\times f$ row-column pairs  of cycle length $\mathrm{lcm}(d,f)$, for
a contribution of

$$c_{\mathrm{lcm}(d,f)}^{df/\mathrm{lcm}(d,f)} =
c_{\mathrm{lcm}(d,f)}^{\gcd(d,f)}.$$

We thus have for the desired cycle index

$$Z(Q_{M,N}) =
\frac{1}{MN}
\sum_{d|M}\sum_{f|N} \varphi(d)\varphi(f)
c_{\mathrm{lcm}(d,f)}^{\gcd(d,f) (M/d)(N/f)}.$$

This  yields for  the count  of configurations  involving at  most $T$
types by Burnside  (colors must be constant on the  cycles, giving the
substitution $c_q = T$)

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{1}{MN}
\sum_{d|M}\sum_{f|N} \varphi(d)\varphi(f)
T^{\gcd(d,f) (M/d)(N/f)}.}$$

This formula  was implemented in  the following Maple code  which also
includes a routine to verify its correctness by total enumeration.

```
with(numtheory);

EX :=
proc(M,N,T)
    1/M/N*
    add(add(phi(d)*phi(f)*T^(gcd(d,f)*M/d*N/f),
            f in divisors(N)), d in divisors(M));
end;

ENUM :=
proc(M,N,T)
option remember;
local idx, d, all, orbit, orbits, rotM, rotN,
    pos, row, col, perm;

    if T = 1 then return 1 fi;

    all := M*N;
    orbits := table();

    for idx from T^all to 2*T^all-1 do
        d := convert(idx, base, T)[1..all];

        orbit := [];

        for rotM from 0 to M-1 do
            for rotN from 0 to N-1 do
                perm := [];
                for pos from 0 to all-1 do
                    col := pos mod N;
                    row := (pos-col)/N;

                    perm :=
                    [op(perm),
                     (row+rotM mod M)*N+
                     (col+rotN mod N)];
                od;

                orbit :=
                [op(orbit),
                 [seq(d[perm[q]+1], q=1..all)]];
            od;
        od;

        orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
    od;

    numelems(orbits);
end;
```

Here are  the colorings using  at most $T$  colors of the  $3\times 2$
case starting with one color / object type:

$$1, 14, 130, 700, 2635, 7826, 19684, 43800, 88725, 
\\ 166870, 295526, 498004, \ldots$$

**Sequel.**  It is  easy  to  compute the  number  of colorings  using
exactly $T$  colors as opposed  to at most  $T$. We get  the following
formula from  first principles  using Stirling  numbers of  the second
kind:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\frac{T!}{MN}
\sum_{d|M}\sum_{f|N} \varphi(d)\varphi(f)
{\gcd(d,f) (M/d)(N/f) \brace T}.}$$

This yields  the following finite  sequence for the $3\times  2$ (with
only six slots available we cannot represent more than six colors):

$$1, 12, 91, 260, 300, 120.$$

The last  term in  this sequence  is a useful  sanity check:  with six
different  colors   all  orbits   have  the   same  size   namely  six
(representing six  permutations from the product  $C_3\times C_2$) and
we indeed obtain $6!/6 = 120.$ This was implemented in Maple as well.

```
with(numtheory);
with(combinat);

EX :=
proc(M,N,T)
    T!/M/N*
    add(add(phi(d)*phi(f)*stirling2(gcd(d,f)*M/d*N/f, T),
            f in divisors(N)), d in divisors(M));
end;

ENUM :=
proc(M,N,T)
option remember;
local idx, d, all, orbit, orbits, rotM, rotN,
    pos, row, col, perm;

    if T = 1 then return 1 fi;

    all := M*N;
    orbits := table();

    for idx from T^all to 2*T^all-1 do
        d := convert(idx, base, T)[1..all];

        if nops(convert(d, `set`)) < T then
            next;
        fi;

        orbit := [];

        for rotM from 0 to M-1 do
            for rotN from 0 to N-1 do
                perm := [];
                for pos from 0 to all-1 do
                    col := pos mod N;
                    row := (pos-col)/N;

                    perm :=
                    [op(perm),
                     (row+rotM mod M)*N+
                     (col+rotN mod N)];
                od;

                orbit :=
                [op(orbit),
                 [seq(d[perm[q]+1], q=1..all)]];
            od;
        od;

        orbits[sort(orbit)[1]] := 1;
    od;

    numelems(orbits);
end;
```

**Addendum.**  There is  another  interpretation of  the problem  that
merits additional investigation,  which is to ask  about the colorings
of the torus  using some exact number  of colors where we  do not only
have translational symmetry of the shapes that appear but also the $T$
colors may be permuted in any one  of $T!$ ways.  What we have here is
a case of **Power Group Enumeration** as defined by Harary and also by
Fripertinger and the answer is simple to compute. We present the Maple
code in order to document the algorithm.  In PGE we have objects being
distributed  into  slots  and  two permutation  groups,  one  of  them
permuting the  slots and  the other  one the objects  and we  seek the
count of  the orbits under this  combined action. In the  present case
there are $M\times N$ slots being  permuted by $C_M\times C_N$ and $T$
objects (colors)  being permuted by  the symmetric group $S_T.$  For a
pair of  permutations from these two  groups we have that  if we cover
the cycles  from the grid  permutation with complete,  consecutive and
directed  copies of  cycles from  the  object permutation  we have  an
assignment  that is  fixed under  the combined  action as  required by
Burnside. Moreover  every cycle  from the  object permutation  must be
used at least  once because we require all colors  to be present. This
means we  need to partition  the cycles  of the grid  permutation into
non-empty    sets,   one    for   each    cycle   from    the   object
permutation. Evidently  this is  possible only if  the lengths  of the
latter  cycles all  divide  the length  of the  cycles  from the  grid
permutation,  which  is  unique  as  seen in  the  closed  form.   The
contribution from  a set of size  $Q$ is $\ell^Q$ where  $\ell$ is the
length  of the  corresponding  cycle. The  total  contribution may  be
extracted from a  basic EGF, the same as with  Stirling numbers of the
second kind as we saw earlier. We get the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
\begin{align} \frac{1}{T!}\frac{1}{MN}
\sum_{\sigma\in S_T}
\sum_{d|M}\sum_{f|N} & \varphi(d)\varphi(f)
[[\forall j_\ell(\sigma) \gt 0: 
\ell\mid\mathrm{lcm}(d,f)]] \\
& \times P(\gcd(d,f) (M/d)(N/f), \sigma) \end{align}}$$

where

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
P(F,\sigma) = F! [z^F] \prod_{\ell=1}^T 
(\exp(\ell z)-1)^{j_\ell(\sigma)}.}$$

Now clearly  when we implement  this we do  not iterate over  all $T!$
permutations but  use the cycle  index instead, which may  be computed
from the standard  recurrence by Lovasz. There is more  on PGE at e.g.
the following  links (various authors) where  the permutation covering
technique   is   explained   in   detail:   [Enumeration   of   finite
automata](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968594/), [Sets of
sequences               with               letters               being
permuted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180525/),      and
[Coloring        a        plane        grid        and        swapping
colors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540602/).

For  example we  obtain  for an  $M\times M$  torus  with exactly  two
swappable colors

$$0, 4, 31, 2107, 671103, 954459519, 5744387279871,\ldots $$

and with three colors

$$0, 3, 345, 447156, 5647919665, 694881637942816, 
\\ 813943290958393433377,\ldots$$

This is the Maple code.

```
with(numtheory);
with(combinat);

pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_flatten_termA :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), [op(1,v), d]];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;


EX :=
proc(M,N,T)
option remember;
local res, len_a, inst_a,
    idx_cols, b, flat_b, cycs_b, lcm_b, gf,
    d, f;

    if M*N < T then return 0 fi;
    if T = 1 then return 1 fi;

    idx_cols := pet_cycleind_symm(T);

    res := 0;

    for b in idx_cols do
        flat_b := pet_flatten_termA(b);
        cycs_b := flat_b[2];

        lcm_b := lcm(seq(op(1, v), v in cycs_b));

        for d in divisors(M) do
            for f in divisors(N) do
                len_a := lcm(d, f);
                inst_a := gcd(d, f)*M/d*N/f;

                if len_a mod lcm_b = 0 and
                inst_a >= degree(b)  then
                    gf :=
                    mul((exp(z*op(1, cycs_b[q]))-1)
                        ^op(2, cycs_b[q]),
                        q=1..nops(cycs_b));

                    res := res +
                    1/M/N*phi(d)*phi(f)*flat_b[1] *
                    inst_a! *
                    coeftayl(gf, z=0, inst_a);
                fi;
            od;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;

ENUM :=
proc(M,N,T)
option remember;
local ind, d, all, orbit, orbitA, orbits, rotM, rotN,
    pos, row, col, perm, conf, pconf;

    if T = 1 then return 1 fi;

    all := M*N;
    orbits := table();

    for ind from T^all to 2*T^all-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, T)[1..all];

        if nops(convert(d, `set`)) < T then
            next;
        fi;

        orbit := [];

        for rotM from 0 to M-1 do
            for rotN from 0 to N-1 do
                perm := [];
                for pos from 0 to all-1 do
                    col := pos mod N;
                    row := (pos-col)/N;

                    perm :=
                    [op(perm),
                     (row+rotM mod M)*N+
                     (col+rotN mod N)];
                od;

                orbit :=
                [op(orbit),
                 [seq(d[perm[q]+1], q=1..all)]];
            od;
        od;

        orbitA := Array(1..M*N*T!); pos := 1;

        perm := firstperm(T);
        while type(perm, `list`) do
            for conf in orbit do
                pconf :=
                subs([seq(q-1=perm[q]-1, q=1..T)], conf);

                orbitA[pos] := pconf;
                pos := pos + 1;
            od;

            perm := nextperm(perm);
        od;

        orbits[sort(orbitA)[1]] := 1;
    od;

    numelems(orbits);
end;
```

Comment: An explicit formula for the solution is very helpful, thank you. This answer also helped me figure out which fixed points I had missed: I had not considered the combinations of both a vertical and horizontal translation. Both of the "all-the-same type" arrangements (`⠀`and  `⠿` ) are the only fixed points of both cases of combining a horizontal translation with either of the two possible vertical translations. Adding those two orbits with two fixed points each into Burnside's formula gives the expected answer of 14.